# Is it possible to separate the input and output of LTXexample such that I can put each in a table cell?

Tags: showexpl

My objective is to create a long tabular list of PSTricks inputs and their corresponding outputs side by side.

The table consists of 3 columns, i.e., **Number** column, **Input** column, & **Output** column. The **Number** column contains hyperlinks to the source code files. For example: if a reader is interested to draw a figure of torus, he just need search in the table and click the number to open its corresponding source code file.

Shortly speaking, how to separate the input and output of LTXexample? My rough idea is as follows:

1. I just pass in the PSTricks routines to a macro in the **Input** column.
2. The macro then provides a saved box containing the output.
3. Then I call another macro (like \usebox) to retrieve the saved box and insert it to the **Output** column.
4. I do step 1-3 for each row. Hyperlink numbers can be easily made using \url (it is not a big problem).

Comment: Is this a proper tabular you want to put things in or do you really really need input and output to be entirely separable, possibly on different pages, possibly the output after another LTXexample etc.?

Comment: Thank for commenting. Actually I just need an immediate output handle for each LTXexample call such that I make 3-column rows in a longtable. Each row is composed of LTXexample in the middle column and its corresponding output handle on the most right column. The most left column displays labels of increasing number. It is more than enough.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a small step in the right direction: instead of producing output, we define two commands \LTXlastexample{in/out}put that still need the width they are to be typeset into. This will require you to output both parts before you issue the next LTXexample, and I've not given much thought to whether it will work beyond my example case, in a spirit of "what could possibly go wrong?"

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showexpl}

\makeatletter
 \newcommand*\SX@put@x[3]{%
    \global\def\LTXlastexampleinput##1{%
      \SX@CodeArea{##1}{#3}%
    }%
    \global\setbox\SX@ResBox\box\SX@ResBox
    \global\def\LTXlastexampleoutput##1{%
      \SX@ResultArea{##1}{#2}%
    }%
 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \begin{LTXexample}[pos=x]
    Hello, world
  \end{LTXexample}

  \show\LTXlastexampleoutput

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \LTXlastexampleinput{5cm} &  \LTXlastexampleoutput{5cm}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how can we make two rows or more?

Comment: @xport: funny, having an LTXexample of this type in a tabular doesn't appear to work.

Comment: I got the solution. It is no longer funny. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a tabular for this. You will have problems with the page breaks. Also it will be difficult to adjust the spaces for the code and the output: sometimes you will probably have a small output but large code lines or the other way round. I would simply put the code and the output side by side with showexpl and use minipage+enumerate or something else to place the numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{pst-calendar}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{LTXexample}[varwidth,pos=r,wide]
\psscalebox{0.5}{%
 \psCalendar[Jahr=2006,Monat=1]}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{minipage}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there have been no LaTeX solution, I will post a ConTeXt solution to give some ideas.

The standard way of doing this soft of thing in ConTeXt is `buffers`. For example:

```
\startbuffer[example1]
 This is a simple metapost example.
 \startMPcode
   draw fullcircle scaled 5cm ;
 \stopMPcode
\stopbuffer

\setupTABLE[col][1][width=0.5\textwidth]
\setupTABLE[col][2][width=0.5\textwidth]

\starttext

\startTABLE
  \NC Input                  \NC Output               \NC \NR
  \NC \typebuffer[example1]  \NC \getbuffer[example1] \NC \NR
\stopTABLE

\stoptext
```

If the snippets are already stored in an external file, then another option is:

```
\startTABLE
   \NC \typefile[example1.tex] \NC \externalfigure[example1.tex] \NC \NR
\stopTABLE
```

When `\externalfigure`, which is equivalent to `\includegraphics` in LaTeX, is given a TeX file, it typesets it in a box and includes the result.

Comment: Thank you. But it will not be usefull for me because I use latex. :-) Your name sounds like Indonesian name.

Comment: If this works for you, then it is relatively easy to port these commands to LaTeX. For the first approach, see [this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5338/latex-equivalent-of-context-buffers). For single page images, the second approach is basically equivalent to `\input` the file in a minipage and scaling the result.