# How to make my unusual environment accept one argument?

Tags: listings, environments, verbatim, fancyvrb

I cannot find a good title to express my question. Therefore, please parse the following code first.

## Minimal Code

```
\documentclass[dvips,dvipsnames,cmyk,table]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array,calc}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\scriptsize,tabsize=3}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{tabsize=3}
\newcommand\gtemp[1]{&&#1\tabularnewline\hline}
\newcommand{\args}{}
\newenvironment{Row}[1]
    {\renewcommand{\args}{#1}\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}}
    {\end{VerbatimOut}\aftergroup\gtemp{\args}}

\newcolumntype{A}
{
  >{\begin{minipage}{0.3333\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}\vspace{\tabcolsep}}%
  c%
  <{\vspace{\tabcolsep}\end{minipage}}%   
}

\newenvironment{ComparisonTable}%
{% 
    \begin{longtable}%
    {%
     |A<{\lstinputlisting{\jobname.tmp}}%
     |A<{\input{\jobname.tmp}}%
     |A%
     |%
    }%
    \hline\ignorespaces%
}%
{\end{longtable}}

\begin{document}
\begin{ComparisonTable}
%
% Row 1
\begin{Row}%
{
 This is a quadratic function.
}
\begin{equation}
 y=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\end{Row}
%
% Row 2
\begin{Row}{LaTeX in action}
\Huge\LaTeXe
\end{Row}
\end{ComparisonTable}
\end{document}
```

## Objective

I want `\Row` to accept an argument such that I can change

```
\begin{Row}
\begin{equation}
 y=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\end{Row}
```

to

```
\begin{Row}{Some description...}
\begin{equation}
 y=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\end{Row}
```

How to do this?

Comment: I think there is a strong hint in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7769/can-this-command-be-converted-to-environment/7791#7791

Comment: @Harald: The business with the `&` is already solved by the `\aftergroup`; see the [previous question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8962/1235) of xport.

Comment: @Hendrik: Um, okay, then. I admit I didn't read the code *that* carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there are two problems with the code you posted: 1. `\aftergroup` can only put *one* token (here `\gtemp`) after the group, and your `\renewcommand` doesn't give a global redefinition, so it won't be in effect after the group. This works:

```
\documentclass[dvips,dvipsnames,cmyk,table]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array,calc}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\scriptsize,tabsize=3}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{tabsize=3}
\newenvironment{Row}[1]
    {\gdef\gtemp{&&#1\tabularnewline\hline}\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}}
    {\end{VerbatimOut}\aftergroup\gtemp}

\newcolumntype{A}
{
  >{\begin{minipage}{0.3333\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}\vspace{\tabcolsep}}%
  c%
  <{\vspace{\tabcolsep}\end{minipage}}%   
}

\newenvironment{ComparisonTable}%
{% 
    \begin{longtable}%
    {%
     |A<{\lstinputlisting{\jobname.tmp}}%
     |A<{\input{\jobname.tmp}}%
     |A%
     |%
    }%
    \hline\ignorespaces%
}%
{\end{longtable}}

\begin{document}
\begin{ComparisonTable}
%
% Row 1
\begin{Row}%
{
 This is a quadratic function.
}
\begin{equation}
 y=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
\end{Row}
%
% Row 2
\begin{Row}{LaTeX in action}
\Huge\LaTeXe
\end{Row}
\end{ComparisonTable}
\end{document}
```