# How to pass an optional argument to an environment with verbatim content?

Tags: environments, verbatim, optional-arguments

This is an attempt to make clear what happened in [this question of xport](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9023/1235) (now deleted, sorry). The now deleted question included code that tried to make my answer to [this question of xport](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9008/how-to-make-my-unusual-environment-accept-one-argument/9012#9012) work for *optional* arguments, but the code failed. A shorter illustration: The following code doesn't compile if one removes the `[optional argument]`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings,fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{Row}[1][]
    {\VerbatimEnvironment
     \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}}
    {\end{VerbatimOut}\lstinputlisting{\jobname.tmp}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Row}[optional argument]
\relax
\end{Row}
\end{document}
```

The error message says

```
! FancyVerb Error:
  Extraneous input `\relax ' between \begin{Row}[<key=value>] and line end
```

Of course, the optional argument (and in fact the whole construction) is utterly pointless here, but hey, it's a minimal example. To make the example in xport's question also work for optional arguments is quite interesting, I think.

The question: What exactly is happening here, and how can one fix the code?

(What I found out so far: `\begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}}` wants to see a linebreak immediately after it (try putting a `%`), and this somehow gets messed up by `\begin{Row}` looking for the optional argument.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: [TH.'s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9040/3323) is much simpler. The one below should depend less on the details of the implementation of `\VerbatimEnvironment`, but that's the only good thing about it.

I propose the following code. The idea is to make a new environment (which I called `Row`, renaming the old `Row` to `oldRow`) check for an optional argument "by hand", and write the relevant thing to a file. Then the file (`\jobname.row`) is read so that `fancyvrb` can happily set the relevant catcodes.

All this can probably be done using `\scantokens`, but I am still quite confused about newlines inside `\scantokens`.

I also added `*#1*` to your definition of the environment: this way, we can check what is going on with the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings,fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{oldRow}[1][]
{*#1*\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}}
  {\end{VerbatimOut}\lstinputlisting{\jobname.tmp}}


\begin{document}

% ==============================================
\makeatletter
\newwrite\RowWrite

\newcommand{\makeallother}{%
  \count0=0\relax 
  \loop\relax 
  \catcode\count0=12\relax 
  \advance\count0 by 1\relax 
  \ifnum\count0<256\relax
  \repeat\relax}

\newenvironment{Row}{%
  \makeallother
  \futurelet\next
  \Row@aux@i}{}

\newcommand{\Row@aux@i}{%
  \def\Row@optional@arg{}%
  \ifx[\next
  \expandafter\Row@grab@until@bracket
  \else
  \expandafter\Row@grab@until@end
  \fi}

\def\Row@grab@until@bracket[#1]{%
  \def\Row@optional@arg{#1}\Row@grab@until@end}

% First expand the \csname...\endcsname,
% then the \string, then the \def.
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\Row@grab@until@end
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter1%
\expandafter\string\csname end{Row}\endcsname{%
  \begingroup%
  \newlinechar=`\^^M%
  \immediate\openout\RowWrite\jobname.row\relax%
  \immediate\write\RowWrite{%
    \string\begin{oldRow}[\Row@optional@arg]#1\string\end{oldRow}%
  }%
  \immediate\closeout\RowWrite%
  \endgroup%
  \end{Row}\input{\jobname.row}%
}

\makeatother
% ==============================================

\begin{Row}
  \relax
  \relax
\end{Row}

\begin{Row}[option]
  \relax
  \relax
\end{Row}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, this really looks a bit complicated. The only thing I immediately understand is the use of the `\expandafter` s `:-)` Thanks nevertheless!

Comment: @Hendrik: I check whether the Row environment has an optional argument, and then write `\begin{oldRow}[...] ... \end{oldRow}` to a file. Eveything is written verbatim (thanks to `\makeallother`). Finally, the whole thing is input. Since I made sure that the optional argument is now there, the old version will now work.

Answer (score 8):

I can answer what is happening, but I don't have a fix for you.

What is happening is that when looking for the optional argument, the `^^M` that got inserted by TeX at the end of the line is tokenized. Since TeX is in state M, and `^^M` has category code 5, this is turned into a space token. LaTeX's `\kernel@ifnextchar` gobbles the space and keeps looking for a nonspace character. It finds `\relax` which isn't `[` so it expands to `\\Row[{}]`.

`\\Row[#1]` has the begin environment code. `\VerbatimOut` changes the category code of `^^M` to active and then looks for an active `^^M` to follow. However, that was already tokenized with catcode 5 and then swallowed. Since it finds `\relax`, it complains.

**Edit:**
If, like me, you have a hard time seeing how the space is getting swallowed by tracing this, the key is this line.

```
\reserved@c  ->\futurelet \@let@token \@ifnch
            ^
```

The extra space that I marked with the caret is part of the definition of `\@xifnch`:

```
\def\:{\@xifnch} \expandafter\def\: {\futurelet\@let@token\@ifnch}
```

**Edit <s>2</s>3:**
Sorry, I should have put a bit a thought into this. This isn't hard to fix. <s>My original comments give the hint of how to fix it, just make `^^M` active!</s> A better solution is to reinsert an active `^^M` character in the case that there is no optional argument. That way the optional argument can be on the next line as in the third use of `\begin{Row}` below.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings,fancyvrb}

\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M\active%
\global\def\activeeol{^^M}%
\endgroup
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Row}{%
        \@ifnextchar[\Row@\Row@noargs
}{%
        \end{VerbatimOut}%
        \lstinputlisting{\jobname.tmp}%
}
\def\Row@[#1]{%
        #1\par
        \VerbatimEnvironment
        \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}%
}
\def\Row@noargs#1{%
        \edef\temp{[]\activeeol\string#1}%
        \expandafter\Row@\temp
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{Row}[optional argument]
\relax
\end{Row}

\begin{Row}
\relax
\end{Row}

\begin{Row}
[Another optional argument]
\relax
\end{Row}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @TH.: It does not work if the optional argument is omitted.

Comment: @xport: It does for me. I made a full minimal example. Does that not work for you?

Comment: @TH.: yours works! However, when I applied it to this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9008/how-to-make-my-unusual-environment-accept-one-argument/9012#9012, it did not work.

Comment: @xport: That question doesn't seem to be related. You deleted the question Hendrik linked to so I guess this is resolved.

Comment: @TH: The link I gave above your comment is the same.

Comment: @xport: No, I linked to your question about one _optional_ argument (which is no longer there); you linked to your question about one _mandatory_ argument.

Comment: @Hendrik: @TH's suggestion is to close the link so I deleted it. The link about the mandatory argument can be modified a bit to match the deleted one. Or I should repost again?

Comment: @xport: TH was right with his suggestion. And please don't modify your question with the mandatory argument: The question is solved and has an accepted answer. You also probably shouldn't repost. Let me read the answers here first; I didn't do that so far.

Comment: @TH.: Thanks for your answer. I'm still in the process of understanding. I'm puzzled since I did try to remove `\@xifnch` from `\@ifnch`, but that didn't help.

Comment: @Hendrik: The issue is that the `^^M` gets tokenized as a space character. I imagine that if you removed the `\@xifnch`, then you get into an infinite loop because the test of the let token (`\@let@token` or something) against `\@sptoken` (or whatever) keeps being true over and over. In any event, once the `^^M` has been tokenized, it's too late to change its catcode so the `\begin{VerbatimOut}` is going to find a token that isn't an active `^^M`. A better solution, perhaps, would be to use `\@ifnextchar[\Row@{\Row@[]\activeeol}` where `\activeeol` is `\let` to an active `^^M`.

Comment: @Hendrik: Okay, that doesn't work. I didn't read the trace output closely enough. `\FV@BeginScanning#1^^M` so it's looking for a literal character. I'll update my answer to the better one.

Comment: @TH.: Ah, OK, I had already been wondering.

Comment: @TH.: Sorry, above I wasn't clear enough. What I tried was: remove the _whole_ `\ifx\@let@token\@sptoken` test from `\@ifnch`; this in particular removes the `\@xifnch`. This way I don't get an infinite loop, but still it doesn't work. That I still can't understand.

Comment: @Hendrik: Still doesn't work meaning it complains about "Extraneous input"? That's what I'd expect. The `\futurelet` has tokenized the `^^M` so it's a space_10 character token. Thus the argument to `\FV@BeginScanning` is the space_10 character and the `\relax` token. `\FV@BeginScanning` checks if `#1` is empty and since it isn't, you get the error.

Comment: @TH.: Seems you're right. But that's really mean of the `\futurelet`, isn't it? I mean, `\futurelet` isn't supposed to mess up anything following it; that's what we love about `\futurelet`. Is this behaviour of `\futurelet` documented anywhere?

Comment: @TH.: Your new version works great. Two comments: 1. In the group where `\activeeol` is defined, the `%` s are somehow not needed. 2. I'd find it easier if the last argument of `\@ifnextchar` was `\expandafter\Row@noarg\activeeol`, with `\def\Row@noarg{\Row@[]}`. By the way, I didn't find this `\futurelet` behaviour in the TeXbook, but in TeXbyTopic it says "If a character token has been `\futurelet` to a control sequence, its category code is fixed. The subsequent `<token1>` cannot change it anymore." Another lesson learned.

Comment: @xport: It's straightforward to make TH's _first_ version of the code work for your optional argument. With his second version I can't get it done; don't know why.

Comment: @Hendrik: Where is the first version and how to apply it to my real scenario?

Comment: @xport: just click on "<n> hours ago".

Comment: @Hendrik: I already tried it. It works but I cannot apply them to my real scenario. See the third comment.

Comment: @xport: I applied it to your real scenario without problems: `\newenvironment{Row}{\catcode\`\^^M\active \@ifnextchar[\Row@{\Row@[]}} {\end{VerbatimOut}\aftergroup\gtemp} \def\Row@[#1]{\gdef\gtemp{&&#1\tabularnewline\hline}\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}}`

Comment: @Hendrik: Thanks, it works. But I noticed some bugs.

Comment: @Hendrik: Re comments, I think that's because TeX is in vertical mode and active `^^M` is `\par` which is (almost completely) ignored in vertical mode. Re `\futurelet`, the text you quoted is familiar. I guess I read it in _TeX by Topic_. I thought it was in _The TeXbook_, but I cannot find it.

Comment: @TH.: Thanks for letting me know that I'm not alone. But I just realized that there's a bug in your code. If you replace `minimal` with `article` and `\relax` with `\large a` in your new code, then you get `! TeX capacity exceeded`. (By the way, do you ever sleep?)

Comment: @Hendrik: Yeah, you're right. The `\large` was getting tokenized. The fix is simple. But I'm starting to think that supporting optional arguments on the next line was a mistake. At any rate, I'll edit the code. As for sleep, I'm going to do so right now!

Comment: @TH.: Oh my, so you've got to play a bit verbatim with `\string` - tricky. And I should have seen it myself, having written "another lesson learned". Once again this `\futurelet` behaviour that I've only learned today. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @xport: In case you didn't see it so far; now you've got another solution.

Comment: @Hendrik: Thanks for informing. I will try to apply it to my real scenario.

Answer (score 4):

As I learned from TH in the comments to his answer, the real culprit is the TeX primitive `\futurelet` that is used to detect if there's an optional argument. If there is none, then the end-of-line character `^^M` (with usually has catcode 5) gets tokenized by the `\futurelet`, meaning that the catcode can't be changed anymore. Now `\begin{VerbatimOut}` changes the catcode of `^^M` to 13 (active), but this has no effect on the `^^M` that is already tokenized, and one gets the error.

Here's another solution along the lines of the definition of `fancyvrb`'s `\FV@Environment`. Unlike TH's solution, it does *not* allow the optional argument to start on the next line  (but it does allow spaces before the `[`). However, this is maybe the right behaviour: Who knows; the code could start with a `[`. Thus, when you compile the code below, then `[Another optional argument]` will be the first line of the third piece of code.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings,fancyvrb}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Row}{%
    \catcode`\^^M=\active
    \@ifnextchar[%
        {\catcode`\^^M=5 \Row@}
        {\catcode`\^^M=5 \Row@[]}
}{%
    \end{VerbatimOut}%
    \lstinputlisting{\jobname.tmp}%
}
\def\Row@[#1]{%
    *#1*\par
    \VerbatimEnvironment
    \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{Row}[optional argument]
\large a
\end{Row}

\begin{Row}
\large a
\end{Row}

\begin{Row}
[Another optional argument]
\large a
\end{Row}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistake, that's essentially what my original "Edit 2" [did](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/9040/revisions). It just made `^^M` active before using `\@ifnextchar`. Then I started adding extra code to handle the optional argument being on the next line.

Comment: @TH.: Yes, almost. That's why (and since I learned the `\futurelet` stuff from you) I made it community wiki. I just wanted to document (mainly for myself) what `\futurelet` does and what the `fancyvrb` way of doing it is.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem with a custom verbatim environment. However, I'm not that savvy with the TeX internals, so I didn't want to mess with the `^^M` stuff described here. (I wouldn't know how to explain it to my coauthors, so I don't want to use it in our paper.)

Instead, I added one required (but unused) argument after the optional argument, and that seems to fix the parsing problem. I.e.,

```
% Original (broken) version
\newenvironment{MyEnv}[1][default-value]{...}{...}

% Updated (work-around) version
\newenvironment{MyEnv}[2][default-value]{...}{...}
%                      ^ extra (unused) explicit arg
```

The usages look like this:

```
\begin{MyEnv}{}
% uses default value
\end{MyEnv}

\begin{MyEnv}[X]{}
% uses custom value "X"
\end{MyEnv}
```

It's obviously not ideal, but again, I found this preferable to adding a bunch of arcane TeX commands that neither I nor my coauthors would understand...

---

<sub>*Note: +1 to the other answers for actually explaining what's happening. If not for the great answers here, I would not have realized that adding an extra argument could be a simple work-around for this issue.*</sub>