# Optional arguments in verbatim environments

Tags: verbatim, optional-arguments

This question is a follow up to [verbatim-like environment with optional arguments poorly behaved](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108897/verbatim-like-environment-with-optional-arguments-poorly-behaved/108916#108916).  Based on David Carlisle's suggestion, I manually looked for an optional argument and employed `\scantokens` to retokenize the text when there were no arguments found.  The only problem that remains is that there is a linefeed after the `\scantoken` that I need to eliminate

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{ifthen} \normalsize
\parskip 1ex\parindent 0em

% SEEMS LIKE IT SHOULD WORK, BUT LACK OF OPTIONAL ARGUMENT MAKES 1ST
% ITEM OF ENVIRONMENT GET EXECUTED AS IF IT WERE OPTIONAL ARGUMENT
%\newenvironment{jenv}[1][]{#1\verbatim}{\endverbatim}

% THIS ALMOST FIXES IT, BUT PUTS LINEFEED AFTER \scantokens
\def\jin#1#2#3{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{[}}%
                {#2\verbatim}%
                 {\verbatim\scantokens{#1#2#3}}%
              }

\newenvironment{jenv}{\jin}{\endverbatim}

\begin{document}

\normalsize
\begin{jenv}[\LARGE]
this is a test
\end{jenv}

\normalsize
\begin{jenv}[\LARGE]
\tiny this is a test
\end{jenv}

\normalsize
\begin{jenv}
this is a test
\end{jenv}

\normalsize
\begin{jenv}
\tiny this is a test
\end{jenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You only want to re-scan `#1` the optional argument don't you?

Comment: Also you don't want to use a normal `\def#1 to look for `[` it will fail completely if the first character is `{`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The MWE makes it look like I could avoid the optional argument altogether and just issue the optional argument prior to invoking an argument-free environment.  However, all of this stuff is going to get stuffed into a box, and so I was hoping to use the optional argument to pre-condition (e.g. define font size or such things) the subsequent verbatim environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{ifthen} \normalsize
\parskip 1ex\parindent 0em

% SEEMS LIKE IT SHOULD WORK, BUT LACK OF OPTIONAL ARGUMENT MAKES 1ST
% ITEM OF ENVIRONMENT GET EXECUTED AS IF IT WERE OPTIONAL ARGUMENT

\newenvironment{jenv}{\verbatim\jenvinner}{\endverbatim}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\jenvinner[1][]{{\nfss@catcodes\scantokens{\gdef\tmp{#1}}}\tmp}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\normalsize
\begin{jenv}[\LARGE]
this is a test
\end{jenv}

\normalsize
\begin{jenv}[\LARGE]
\tiny this is a test
\end{jenv}

\normalsize
\begin{jenv}
this is a test
\end{jenv}


\normalsize
\begin{jenv}
\tiny this is a test
\end{jenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your facility with arcane TeX structures is most impressive.  Thanks so much!