# Command for special text with reserved LaTeX symbols

Tags: symbols, hyphenation

Surely I am missing something here, but I can't remember =(. I want to build a command that accepts special LaTeX symbols and correctly display them. As special I mean `\`, `_`, or some others, and respect spaces, page/line breaks. The special text can be in `\rmfamily` or `\ttfamily` and no hyphenation is desirable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\specialtext}{\ttfamily #1}

\begin{document}

\specialtext{This a special text with \ # _}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean `\verb`?

Comment: More or less like `\verb`, but with more options. After posting the question I thought about something like inline `listings`, but it seems to much for this operation.

Comment: To respect things like `\rmfamily`, I presume you mean that it is specified prior to entry into the command/environment, since otherwise it would display literally, rather than being enacted?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) provides an inline command, `\lstinline`. It has an optional argument for all the settings you want. There's also `\lstMakeShortInline` which defines a shortcut for `\lstinline` where you can have preset options for the specified shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to a trick from David Carlisle (see [Optional arguments in verbatim environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109030/optional-arguments-in-verbatim-environments)), he helped me with the following (EDITED for T1 encoding, per egreg's suggestion):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{readarray}
\renewcommand\encodingdefault{T1}
\parskip 1ex\parindent 0em

\newenvironment{venv}{\verbatim\venvinner}{\endverbatim}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\venvinner[1][]{{\nfss@catcodes\scantokens{\gdef\tmp{#1}}}\tmp}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\normalsize
\begin{venv}[\LARGE]
this is a test of \LARGE verbatim
\end{venv}

Back to normal text outside of verbatim

\normalsize
\begin{venv}[\large]
\tiny this is a test of \large verbatim
that begins with a \ character, which
is tricky business when using optional 
arguments in a verbatim environment.
\end{venv}

Back to normal text outside of verbatim

\normalsize

\begin{venv}[\rmfamily]
Here is verbatim text in \rmfamily.
\end{venv}

\begin{venv}[\slshape]
And we have verbatim in \slshape
\end{venv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

p.s. I would add in closing that the `verbatimbox` package incorporates this kind of [optional pre-conditioning] logic in order to stuff verbatim into a box.  But in that case, it must display on a single page, as a box cannot be broken across pages.

Comment: A backslash is printed as such if you use T1-encoded fonts.