# Use sans-serif in a verbatim environment?

Tags: fonts, formatting, verbatim, sans-serif, fancyvrb

What is the right way get `fancyvrb`’s verbatim environment (or any other variation) to use `\textsf` as the font?

I can do it with:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
  \textsf{Here’s some textsf.}
\end{Verbatim}
```

I would have expected something analogous to the following to work:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[fontfamily=helvetica]
  Here’s some Helvetica.
\end{Verbatim}
```

but none of the variations I’ve tried (`[fontfamily=sf]`, `[fontfamily=textsf]`, `[fontshape=sf]`, and half a dozen others) seems to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar as the definition for the `tt` fontfamily, you can build a `sf` family to use `\sffamily`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`\`=\active
\gdef\FV@fontfamily@sf{%
  \def\FV@FontScanPrep{\FV@MakeActive\`}%
  \def\FV@FontFamily{\sffamily\edef`{{\string`}}}}
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent Text before
\begin{Verbatim}[fontfamily=sf]
  Here's some Sans Serif font.
\end{Verbatim}
Text after

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since in your question you said "or any other variation", here's an example using the `lstlisting` environment from the `listings` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\sffamily,columns=flexible}

\begin{document}

\noindent Text before
\begin{lstlisting}
  Here's some Sans Serif font.
\end{lstlisting}
Text after

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's now another option, this time using the `listings` interface to `fancyvrb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{fancyvrb=true,basicstyle=\sffamily,columns=flexible}

\begin{document}

\noindent Text before
\begin{Verbatim}
  Here's some Sans Serif font.
\end{Verbatim}
Text after

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Maybe simply:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
%\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ttfamily} % original one
\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\sffamily}
\makeatother

\begin{verbatim}
Sans serif,
indeed.
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, but he writes ``fancyvrb’s verbatim environment (OR ANY OTHER variation)''. So why not the simplest solution?

Answer (score 3):

As shown in [Command for special text with reserved LaTeX symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111966/command-for-special-text-with-reserved-latex-symbols/111976#111976),

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\renewcommand\encodingdefault{T1}
\newenvironment{venv}{\verbatim\venvinner}{\endverbatim}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\venvinner[1][]{{\nfss@catcodes\scantokens{\gdef\tmp{#1}}}\tmp}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{venv}[\sffamily]
This should be \verbatim in sans serif
\end{venv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` be cleaner than `\renewcommand\encodingdefault{T1}`? Or there's some drawback?

Comment: @tohecz I'll have to take your word. I'm ignorant on which usage is preferred. I only know it gets the job done.