# Listings: add vertical padding without abusing frame

Tags: spacing, listings, vertical-alignment

I have the following setup for my displayed listings:

> [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor,lipsum}

\lstset{
    backgroundcolor = \color{yellow},
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    columns = fullflexible,
    tabsize = 4,
    frame = leftline,
    framesep = 0pt,
    framexleftmargin = 3pt,
    framerule = 2pt,
    rulecolor = \color{green!50!black},
    xrightmargin = -3pt,
    numbers = left,
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fermentum aliquam ipsum at consequat. Nam id aliquam ex, a auctor augue laoreet.
\begin{lstlisting}
Hello, world!

\bye
\end{lstlisting}
\noindent\lipsum*[4]

\end{document}
```

Particularly, I have:

- `tt` font;
- background color;
- decorative line along the left margin of the listing;
- the background protruding into the page margins.

Now I would like to add top and bottom padding to the listing, like this:

> [image]

The standard way would be to add a yellow frame around the listing. However, it seems I can't do that because I can't have two frames: one yellow and one green. So how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I am in the process of upgrading my `verbatimbox` package to provide some code (not syntax) highlighting tools (see draft package revision below). I was able to achieve somewhat your goal of added vertical buffer with one limitation.  Because the yellow colorfield is drawn for each verbatim line, if it reaches vertically too far upward, it overwrites the descenders of the prior verbatim line.  Thus, in this example, I found I could only set it (`\vbxcolorfieldoverlap`) as large as 1.4pt without commencing overlap.  Perhaps that is enough for your taste.  This parameter was originally introduced to be a small positive value to prevent an occasional thin white line between successive verbatim rows, but I found in this case I could make it larger to produce a top/bottom color buffer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,xcolor}
\def\vbxnumberformat{\arabic{VerbboxLineNo}\kern1ex\textcolor{green!50!black}{%
  \rule[\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox-\vbxcolorfieldoverlap\relax]{2pt}{%
        \dimexpr\baselineskip+2\vbxcolorfieldoverlap\relax}}}
\def\vbxcodestyle{\ttfamily\normalsize\strut}
\def\vbxnumberstyle{\rmfamily\normalsize}
\setlength\vbxnumbergap{0pt}
\setvbxfieldwidth[3pt]{\dimexpr\textwidth+6pt\relax}
\VerbCodeIndent=-3pt\relax
\vbxContinueLineNoAfter
\def\vbxformat{%
  \vbxnum%
  \vbxfieldcolor[yellow]%
  \hspace{\vbxleftfieldwidth}%
  \vbxcodestyle%
}
\begin{document}
\setlength\vbxcolorfieldoverlap{1.4pt}%
This has 1.4pt vertical buffer (any more overlaps prior verbatim line):
\begin{verbnobox}[\vbxformat]
Hello World!
    this is a y descender
bye
\end{verbnobox}
\setlength\vbxcolorfieldoverlap{0pt}%
This has no vertical buffer:
\begin{verbnobox}[\vbxformat]
Hello World! continued
    this is a y descender
bye
\end{verbnobox}
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is my draft version of V4.00 `verbatimbox.sty`, which was used with the MWE.

```
\def\verbatimboxVersionNumber{v4.00 }
\ProvidesPackage{verbatimbox}
        [2015/03/25 \verbatimboxVersionNumber
Routines for placing verbatim text into boxes, useful in places where
the verbatim environment is inaccessible.  Secondarily, for adding
vertical buffer around an object.]
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Steven B. Segletes.
%
% verbatimbox.sty is based on boxedverbatim environment found
% in moreverb.sty.
%
% An enabling routine, \addvbuffer[]{} shares some functional
% similarities to \raisebox, but it is not the same.
%
% 2.01 -Added LPPL License info to package
% 3.0  -Added myverbbox environment
%      -Corrected problem when no optional arguments are passed to
%         verbbox environment
%      -Added optional arguments to \addvbuffer
%      -Fixed \verbfilebox so that it restored \verbatim@processline
%      -Produced real documentation
% 3.01 -renamed \macro@name so as not to conflict with (I think) ltxdoc
%       package
% 3.1  -Corrected default argument to \addvbuffer so that it wouldn't
%       break.  Also, gave better guidance in documentation to use
%       of optional argument to \addvbuffer
%      -Added verbnobox environment and \verbfilenobox macro
%      -Improved documentation showing line-specific optional arguments
% 3.11 -Eliminated the use of the stringstrings package, which resets
%       the definition of \|
% 3.12 -Corrected bug introduced in V3.11, which occured with [t] 
%       option to \theverbbox
%      -When using two lengths in \addvbuffer optional argument,
%       they MUST be individually in {}, rather than "~" or "\ " between
% 3.13 -Corrected residual bug from V3.11, when \addvbuffer called
%       without an optional argument.
% 4.00 -Added cverbbox and mycverbbox environments for color
%      -Added host of code highlighting routines.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\@ifundefined{verbatim@processline}{\RequirePackage{verbatim}}{}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{readarray}

% Following 3 lines thanks to Prof. Enrico Gregorio, from: 
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42318/
%   removing-a-backslash-from-a-character-sequence
\begingroup\lccode`\|=`\\
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\removebs#1{\if#1|\else#1\fi}}
\newcommand{\@macro@name}[1]{\expandafter\removebs\string#1}
%

\newcounter{VerbboxLineNo}
\newlength\VerbCodeIndent
\newcommand\vbxstartline[1]{\setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}}
\newcommand\vbxContinueLineNoAfter{\let\vbx@lineprotocol\vbx@continuelineno}
\newcommand\vbxResetLineNoAfter{\let\vbx@lineprotocol\vbx@resetlineno}
\newcommand\vbx@continuelineno{\resetvbxtitle}
\newcommand\vbx@resetlineno{\setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{0}\resetvbxtitle}
\vbxResetLineNoAfter
\vbxstartline{1}
\global\newsavebox{\savedverbbox}
%%%%%ORIGINAL FORM%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The verbbox environment is based on 
% the boxedverbatim environment found in moreverb.sty
% The optional argument allows the user to modify properties of the text
%   such as fontsize
%
\newenvironment{origverbbox}[1][]{%
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
    {\setbox0=\hbox{\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\par}}%
  \@minipagetrue%
  \@tempswatrue%
  \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup #1 \verbatim
}
{%
  \endverbatim
  \unskip\setbox0=\lastbox %
  \egroup
  \global\sbox{\savedverbbox}{\box0}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% David Carlisle provided the \verbbox@inner approach to avoid
% problem when no optional argument is provided to verbbox environment:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109030/optional-arguments-in
%   -verbatim-environments
\newcommand\verbbox@inner[1][]{{\nfss@catcodes\scantokens{\gdef\@tmp{#1}}}}
\def\@tmp{}

\newenvironment{verbbox}{%
  \addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}%
% FOR SOME REASON, USING \my@par INSTEAD OF \par PREVENTS EXTRA SPACE
% ABOVE verbbox WHEN USING OPTIONAL ARGUMENTS
  \let\my@par\par%
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
%   FIRST \@tmp APPLIES OPTIONAL ARGUMENT TO EACH VERBATIM LINE
%   SECOND \@tmp MAKES SURE ANY PRINTED MATTER OF OPTIONAL ARGUMENT
%   IS ACCOUNTED FOR IN VERBATIM BOX WIDTH
    {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
    \rule{\VerbCodeIndent}{0pt}%
    \@tmp\setbox0=\hbox{\@tmp\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\my@par}}%
  \@minipagetrue%
  \@tempswatrue%
  \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup \verbatim\verbbox@inner%
}
{%
  \endverbatim%
  \unskip\setbox0=\lastbox %
  \egroup%
  \global\sbox{\savedverbbox}{\box0\rule{\VerbCodeIndent}{0pt}}%
  \global\def\@tmp{}%
  \global\vbx@lineprotocol%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The myverbbox environment is altered from verbbox environment
% The optional argument allows the user to modify properties of 
%   the text such as fontsize
% The mandatory argument is a command which is formed so as to
%   regurgitate the boxed content created within the environment
%
\newenvironment{myverbbox}[2][]{%
%  \addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}%
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
% THE FIRST #1 ACCOUNTS FOR NON-PRINTING COMMANDS; THE SECOND #1 IS FOR
% PRINTED OPTIONAL MATERIAL
    {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
    \rule{\VerbCodeIndent}{0pt}%
    #1\setbox0=\hbox{#1\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\par}}%
  \@minipagetrue%
  \@tempswatrue%
  \global\edef\sv@name{\@macro@name{#2}}%
  \@ifundefined{\sv@name content}{%
    \expandafter\newsavebox\expandafter{\csname\sv@name content\endcsname}%
  }%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\edef\csname\sv@name\endcsname{\usebox{%
  \csname\sv@name content\endcsname}}%
  \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup \verbatim
}
{%
  \endverbatim%
  \unskip\setbox0=\lastbox %
  \egroup%
  \global\sbox{\csname\sv@name content\endcsname}{%
    \box0\rule{\VerbCodeIndent}{0pt}}%
  \global\vbx@lineprotocol%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The verbfilebox command is like the verbbox environment, but takes
% a file as input, rather than text typed into an environment.
% The optional argument allows the user to modify properties of the text
% such as fontsize
% Example: \verbfilebox[\scriptsize]{myfile}

\let\sv@verbatim@processline\verbatim@processline

\newcommand\verbfilebox[2][]{%
%  \addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}%
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
    {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
    \rule{\VerbCodeIndent}{0pt}%
    #1\setbox0=\hbox{#1\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\par}}%
  \@minipagetrue%
  \@tempswatrue%
  \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup \verbatiminput{#2}
  \unskip\setbox0=\lastbox %
  \egroup
  \global\sbox{\savedverbbox}{\box0}
  \let\verbatim@processline\sv@verbatim@processline
  \global\vbx@lineprotocol%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\theverbbox[1][x]{%
  \if #1t%
%   The t option is for outputting the savedverbbox inside a tabular
%   environment (else insufficent vertical space above box)
    \addvbuffer[{\boxtopsep} {\boxbottomsep}]{\usebox{\savedverbbox}}%
  \else%
    \usebox{\savedverbbox}%
  \fi%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \addvbuffer is based on \fbox, 
% but without a frame.  Empty buffer space
% is added above and below the object, making a new box.
% An optional argument can specify the buffer spaces or, if no
% optional argument is specified:
% above the box is added \boxtopsep (initially 3pt) vertical space;
% below the box is added \boxbottomsep (initially 0pt) vertical space.
%
\newdimen\boxtopsep
\newdimen\boxbottomsep
\newdimen\ps@tempdima
\newbox\ps@tempboxa
\setlength\boxtopsep{3pt}
\setlength\boxbottomsep{0pt}
\long\def\add@vbuffer#1{\leavevmode\setbox\ps@tempboxa\hbox{#1}\ps@tempdima
   0pt \advance\ps@tempdima \dp\ps@tempboxa \hbox{\lower\ps@tempdima\hbox
  {\vbox{\hbox{\vbox{\vskip\boxtop@sep \box\ps@tempboxa \vskip 
  \boxbottom@sep}}}}}}

\global\newlength\boxtop@sep
\global\newlength\boxbottom@sep
\newcommand\addvbuffer[2][{\boxtopsep} {\boxbottomsep}]{%
  \getargsC{#1}%
  \setlength\boxtop@sep{\argi}%
  \if1\narg\setlength\boxbottom@sep{\argi}\else%
           \setlength\boxbottom@sep{\argii}\fi%
  \add@vbuffer{#2}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The following two "nobox" commands are basically versions of
% \verbatiminput and \verbatim that have been adapted to take the
% optional argument style of this package.  No boxes are created,
% but breaking across page boundaries is not a problem here, as
% it would be with a box.

\newcommand\verbfilenobox[2][]{%
%  \addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}%
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
    {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
    \rule{\VerbCodeIndent}{0pt}%
    #1\setbox0=\hbox{#1\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\par}}%
  \verbatiminput{#2}
  \let\verbatim@processline\sv@verbatim@processline
  \global\vbx@lineprotocol%
}

\newenvironment{verbnobox}{%
  \gdef\startstate{T}%
  \addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}%
% FOR SOME REASON, USING \my@par INSTEAD OF \par PREVENTS EXTRA SPACE
% ABOVE verbbox WHEN USING OPTIONAL ARGUMENTS
  \let\my@par\par%
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
%   FIRST \@tmp APPLIES OPTIONAL ARGUMENT TO EACH VERBATIM LINE
%   SECOND \@tmp MAKES SURE ANY PRINTED MATTER OF OPTIONAL ARGUMENT
%   IS ACCOUNTED FOR IN VERBATIM BOX WIDTH
    {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
    \if T\startstate\gdef\startstate{F}\else\rule{\VerbCodeIndent}{0pt}\fi%
    \@tmp\setbox0=\hbox{\@tmp\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\my@par}}%
\verbatim\verbbox@inner%
}
{%
  \endverbatim%
  \global\def\@tmp{}%
  \global\vbx@lineprotocol%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The cverbbox and mycverbbox macros add color capability to 
% verbbox'es.  In addition to the standard optional argument
% that is supported by this package, cverbbox additionally
% takes 3 mandatory arguments: font color, background color,
% and frame color. The mycverbbox environment additionally
% takes a verbbox name as a final argument.

\newenvironment{mycverbbox}[5][]{%
%  \addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}%
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
% THE FIRST #1 ACCOUNTS FOR NON-PRINTING COMMANDS; THE SECOND #1 IS FOR
% PRINTED OPTIONAL MATERIAL
    {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
    \rule{\VerbCodeIndent}{0pt}%
    #1\setbox0=\hbox{#1\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\par}}%
  \@minipagetrue%
  \@tempswatrue%
  \global\edef\sv@name{\@macro@name{#5}}%
  \global\edef\cverbboxColor{#3}%
  \global\edef\cverbboxFColor{#4}%
  \@ifundefined{\sv@name content}{%
    \expandafter\newsavebox\expandafter{\csname\sv@name content\endcsname}%
  }%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\edef\csname\sv@name\endcsname{\usebox{%
  \csname\sv@name content\endcsname}}%
  \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\color{#2} \verbatim
}
{%
  \endverbatim%
  \unskip\setbox0=\lastbox %
  \egroup%
  \setbox1=\hbox{%
    \colorbox{\cverbboxColor}{\box0\rule{\VerbCodeIndent}{0pt}}}%
  \global\sbox{\csname\sv@name content\endcsname}%
    {%
      \fboxsep=\fboxrule\colorbox{\cverbboxFColor}{\box1}}%
  \global\vbx@lineprotocol%
}
\newenvironment{cverbbox}[4][]{%
%  \addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}%
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
% THE FIRST #1 ACCOUNTS FOR NON-PRINTING COMMANDS; THE SECOND #1 IS FOR
% PRINTED OPTIONAL MATERIAL
    {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
    \rule{\VerbCodeIndent}{0pt}%
    #1\setbox0=\hbox{#1\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\par}}%
  \@minipagetrue%
  \@tempswatrue%
  \global\edef\cverbboxColor{#3}%
  \global\edef\cverbboxFColor{#4}%
  \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\color{#2} \verbatim
}
{%
  \endverbatim%
  \unskip\setbox0=\lastbox %
  \egroup%
  \setbox1=\hbox{%
    \colorbox{\cverbboxColor}{\box0\rule{\VerbCodeIndent}{0pt}}}%
  \global\sbox{\savedverbbox}{%
    \fboxsep=\fboxrule\colorbox{\cverbboxFColor}{\box1}}%
  \global\vbx@lineprotocol%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Here are a series of macros for highlighting code (not syntax
% highlighting),

\newlength\vbxcolorfieldoverlap
\newlength\vbxfieldwidth
\newlength\@vbxcommentindent
\newlength\@vbxcommentwidth
\newlength\vbxcommentrule
\newlength\vbxcommentsep
\newlength\vbxtitlerule
\newlength\vbxtitlesep
\newlength\vbxnumbergap
\newlength\vbxleftfieldwidth
\newlength\gvbxfieldwidth
\newlength\gvbxleftfieldwidth
\newsavebox\@thevbxcolorfield
\setlength\@vbxcommentindent{.75\vbxfieldwidth}
\setlength\@vbxcommentwidth{.24\vbxfieldwidth}
\newcounter{vbxcount}
% USER MODIFIABLE
\setlength\vbxcolorfieldoverlap{.1pt}% PREVENTS THIN WHITE LINES IN LISTING
\def\vbxdefaultcolorfield{black!5}
\setlength\vbxnumbergap{2pt}
\def\vbxnumberformat{\arabic{VerbboxLineNo}:}
\def\vbxnumberstyle{\sffamily\scriptsize}
\def\vbxcodestyle{\ttfamily\footnotesize\strut}
\setlength\vbxleftfieldwidth{0pt}
\setlength\vbxfieldwidth{\linewidth}
%
\def\vbxcommentstyle{\vbxcodestyle\rmfamily}
\def\vbxcommenttextcolor{blue!70!black}
\def\vbxcommentfieldcolor{yellow!13}
\def\vbxcommentrulecolor{red}
\setlength\vbxcommentrule{1pt}
\setlength\vbxcommentsep{1pt}
%
\def\vbxtitlestyle{\centering\rmfamily\small}
\def\vbxtitletextcolor{black}
\def\vbxtitlefieldcolor{yellow!25}
\def\vbxtitlerulecolor{black}
\setlength\vbxtitlerule{.5pt}
\setlength\vbxtitlesep{1pt}

%%%%%
\newcommand\@setcolorvbxfield[1]{%
  \savebox{\@thevbxcolorfield}{%
    \smash{\makebox[0pt][l]{\vbxcodestyle\textcolor{#1}{%
    \rule[\dimexpr-\vbxcolorfieldoverlap-\dp\strutbox]{\vbxfieldwidth}%
      {\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox+2\vbxcolorfieldoverlap}}}}}%
}

\newcommand\vbxfieldcolor[1][\vbxdefaultcolorfield]{\@setcolorvbxfield{#1}\usebox{\@thevbxcolorfield}}

\newcommand\vbxnum[1][0ex]{\makebox[#1][r]{\smash{%
  \vbxnumberstyle\vbxnumberformat}\hspace{\vbxnumbergap}}}

\newcommand\vbxnumstyle[2][0ex]{\makebox[#1][r]{\smash{%
  \vbxnumberstyle#2\vbxnumberformat}\hspace{\vbxnumbergap}}}

\newcommand\vbxnumcolor[2][0ex]{\makebox[#1][r]{\smash{%
  \textcolor{#2}{\vbxnumberstyle\vbxnumberformat}}\hspace{\vbxnumbergap}}}

\newcommand*\invbxline[3]{\ifnum\value{VerbboxLineNo}=#1\relax#2\else#3\fi}

\newcommand*\invbxlines[4]{%
  \ifnum\value{VerbboxLineNo}<#1\relax#4\else%
    \ifnum\value{VerbboxLineNo}>#2#4\else#3\fi%
  \fi%
}

\newcommand\vbxcomment[2][]{\vbxcodestyle#1\fboxsep=0pt\smash{\rlap{%
  \textcolor{\vbxcommentrulecolor}{%
     \rule[-\vbxcommentrule]{\@vbxcommentindent}{\vbxcommentrule}%
     \ifdim\@vbxcommentindent<0pt\relax%
       \rlap{\rule[-\vbxcommentrule]{-\@vbxcommentindent}{\vbxcommentrule}}%
     \fi%
  }%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\vbxcommentsep}{%
    \textcolor{\vbxcommentrulecolor}{\colorbox{\vbxcommentfieldcolor}{%
      \fboxsep=\vbxcommentsep%
      \fboxrule=\vbxcommentrule%
      \fbox{\parbox[b]{%
        \dimexpr\@vbxcommentwidth-2\vbxcommentrule-2\vbxcommentsep}%
        {\color{\vbxcommenttextcolor}\vbxcommentstyle%
         #1\strut#2\strut}}}}}}}%
}

\newcommand\setvbxfieldwidth[2][0pt]{%
  \setlength\vbxfieldwidth{#2}%
  \global\setlength\gvbxfieldwidth{\vbxfieldwidth}%
  \setlength\vbxleftfieldwidth{#1}%
  \global\setlength\gvbxleftfieldwidth{\vbxleftfieldwidth}%
}

\newcommand\vbxcommentwidth[2][-\textwidth]{%
  \setlength\@vbxcommentwidth{#2}%
  \ifdim#1>-\textwidth\setlength\@vbxcommentindent{#1}\else%
    \setlength\@vbxcommentindent{%
      \dimexpr\vbxfieldwidth-#2-\vbxtitlerule\relax}\fi%
}

\newcommand\mastervbxtitle[1]{\fboxsep=0pt%
  \rule{-\vbxleftfieldwidth}{0pt}%
  \textcolor{\vbxtitlerulecolor}{\colorbox{\vbxtitlefieldcolor}{%
      \fboxsep=\vbxtitlesep%
      \fboxrule=\vbxtitlerule%
      \fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\vbxfieldwidth-2\vbxtitlerule-2\vbxtitlesep%
        +\vbxleftfieldwidth\relax}{%
    \vbxtitlestyle\textcolor{\vbxtitletextcolor}{#1}}}}}\\%
  \rule{\VerbCodeIndent}{0pt}%
  \global\let\vbxtitle\@gobble%
}

\def\resetvbxtitle{\global\let\vbxtitle\mastervbxtitle}
\resetvbxtitle

\newcommand\vbxrebox[1]{%
  \hspace{\dimexpr\gvbxleftfieldwidth-\VerbCodeIndent\relax}%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\gvbxfieldwidth+\VerbCodeIndent\relax][l]{#1}}


\newcommand\vbxrefbox[1]{%
  \fboxrule=\vbxtitlerule\relax%
  \fboxsep=-\fboxrule%
  \textcolor{\vbxtitlerulecolor}{\fbox{\vbxrebox{#1}}}%
}

\def\thenextvbxcount{\stepcounter{vbxcount}\thevbxcount}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\endinput
```

If you want to see some of the things that I hope to have it do, compile the following code with the above style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\def\vbxcodestyle{\ttfamily\scriptsize\strut}

\#1

%  \setvbxfieldwidth[.06\linewidth]{.74\linewidth}%
\def\vbxformat{%
  \vbxtitlerule=1pt\relax%
  \setvbxfieldwidth[.06\linewidth]{.74\linewidth}%
  \vbxtitle{%
    Verbbox \thenextvbxcount. This is the title.}%
  \vbxfieldcolor%
  \vbxnum%
  \invbxline{11}{\vbxcommentwidth{.22\vbxfieldwidth}%
    \vbxcomment{I am drawing attention to ``Hello World''}}{}%
  \invbxline{15}{\vbxcommentwidth{.22\vbxfieldwidth}%
    \vbxcomment[\normalsize]{I like \LaTeX{}}}{}%
  \vbxcodestyle%
}

\begin{verbbox}[\vbxformat]
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
/* Block
 * comment */

int main()
{
    int i;

    // Line comment.
    puts("Hello world!");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        puts("LaTeX is also great for programmers!");
    }

    return 0;
}
\end{verbbox}
{\noindent\centering\vbxrebox{\theverbbox}\par}



\#2

%\setvbxfieldwidth[.23\linewidth]{.74\linewidth}%
\def\vbxformat{%
 \setvbxfieldwidth[.23\linewidth]{.74\linewidth}%
 \vbxtitle{%
    Verbbox \thenextvbxcount. This is the title\\ for my code on\\\today{}}%
  \invbxline{1}{%
    \vbxfieldcolor[green!8]\vbxnumcolor{green!75!black}%
  }{%
    \invbxlines{3}{4}{%
      \vbxfieldcolor\vbxnumstyle{\color{red}\normalsize$\rightarrow$}%
    }{%
      \invbxlines{8}{18}{%
        \vbxfieldcolor[blue!12!gray!15]\vbxnumcolor{black!20}%
     }{%
      \vbxfieldcolor[cyan!3]\vbxnum%
     }%
    }%
  }%
  \invbxline{11}{\vbxcommentwidth{.22\vbxfieldwidth}%
    \vbxcomment{I am drawing attention to ``Hello World''}}{}%
  \invbxline{15}{\vbxcommentwidth[-.3\vbxfieldwidth]{.22\vbxfieldwidth}%
    \vbxcomment[\normalsize]{I like \LaTeX{}}}{}%
  \vbxcodestyle\,%
}


\begin{verbbox}[\vbxformat]
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
/* Block
 * comment */

int main()
{
    int i;

    // Line comment.
    puts("Hello world!");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        puts("LaTeX is also great for programmers!");
    }

    return 0;
}
\end{verbbox}
{\noindent\centering\vbxrefbox{\theverbbox}\par}


\noindent x\hrulefill x

\#3
\VerbCodeIndent=.06\linewidth\relax
\def\vbxformat{%
 \setvbxfieldwidth[.06\linewidth]{.94\linewidth}%
  \vbxtitlerule=1pt\relax%
  \vbxtitle{%
    Verbbox \thenextvbxcount. This is the title. for a nobox environment,
    which allows for page breaks}%
  \vbxfieldcolor%
  \vbxnum%
  \invbxline{11}{\vbxcommentwidth{.22\vbxfieldwidth}%
    \vbxcomment{I am drawing attention to ``Hello World''}}{}%
  \invbxline{15}{\vbxcommentwidth{.22\vbxfieldwidth}%
    \vbxcomment[\normalsize]{I like \LaTeX{}}}{}%
  \vbxcodestyle%
}
\begin{verbnobox}[\vbxformat]
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
int main()
{
    int i;
    // Line comment.
    puts("Hello world!");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        puts("LaTeX is also great for programmers!");
    }
    return 0;
}
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
int main()
{
    int i;
    // Line comment.
    puts("Hello world!");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        puts("LaTeX is also great for programmers!");
    }
    return 0;
}
\end{verbnobox}
\noindent x\hrulefill x



\#4
\def\vbxformat{%
% \setvbxfieldwidth[.06\linewidth]{.94\linewidth}%
  \vbxtitlerule=1pt\relax%
  \vbxtitle{%
    Verbbox \thenextvbxcount. This is the title.}%
  \vbxfieldcolor%
  \vbxnum%
  \invbxline{4}{\vbxcommentwidth{.22\vbxfieldwidth}%
    \vbxcomment[\normalsize]{I like \LaTeX{}}}{}%
  \vbxcodestyle%
}

\VerbCodeIndent=38pt\relax
\setvbxfieldwidth[.05\linewidth]{.87\linewidth}%

\noindent\verbfilenobox[\vbxformat]{samplecode.txt}


\#5

\verbfilebox[\vbxformat]{samplecode.txt}

{\centering\vbxrefbox{\theverbbox}\par}


\#6

\begin{myverbbox}[\vbxformat]{\myvb}
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    puts("LaTeX is also great for programmers!");
}
return 0;
\end{myverbbox}
\noindent\myvb

{\centering\vbxrebox{\myvb}\par}

\#7

\fboxrule=2pt
\VerbCodeIndent=66pt\relax

\begin{cverbbox}[\scriptsize\vbxnum]{blue}{cyan!5}{green}
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    puts("LaTeX is also great for programmers!");
}
return 0;
\end{cverbbox}
\noindent\theverbbox


\#8

\VerbCodeIndent=44pt\relax

\begin{mycverbbox}[\tiny]{blue}{cyan!5}{green}{mycvb}
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    puts("LaTeX is also great for programmers!");
}
return 0;
\end{mycverbbox}
\noindent\mycvb


\#9

\VerbCodeIndent=44pt\relax

\begin{verbbox}[\tiny]
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    puts("LaTeX is also great for programmers!");
}
return 0;
\end{verbbox}
\noindent\fbox{\theverbbox}



\#10

\VerbCodeIndent=66pt\relax

\begin{myverbbox}[\tiny]{\myvb}
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    puts("LaTeX is also great for programmers!");
}
return 0;
\end{myverbbox}
\noindent\fbox{\myvb}

\end{document}
```

The idea is that you use the optional argument to `verbatimbox` macros to "program" the appearance of the verbatim.

Thus a `verbatimbox` format like this could produce the following result, when applied to its given verbatim content (this example is overboard in a gaudy way, but I was just trying to cram in features to show the types of things it can adjust):

```
\def\vbxformat{%
 \setvbxfieldwidth[.23\linewidth]{.74\linewidth}%
 \vbxtitle{%
    Verbbox \thenextvbxcount. This is the title\\ for my code on\\\today{}}%
  \invbxline{1}{%
    \vbxfieldcolor[green!8]\vbxnumcolor{green!75!black}%
  }{%
    \invbxlines{3}{4}{%
      \vbxfieldcolor\vbxnumstyle{\color{red}\normalsize$\rightarrow$}%
    }{%
      \invbxlines{8}{18}{%
        \vbxfieldcolor[blue!12!gray!15]\vbxnumcolor{black!20}%
     }{%
      \vbxfieldcolor[cyan!3]\vbxnum%
     }%
    }%
  }%
  \invbxline{11}{\vbxcommentwidth{.22\vbxfieldwidth}%
    \vbxcomment{I am drawing attention to ``Hello World''}}{}%
  \invbxline{15}{\vbxcommentwidth[-.3\vbxfieldwidth]{.22\vbxfieldwidth}%
    \vbxcomment[\normalsize]{I like \LaTeX{}}}{}%
  \vbxcodestyle\,%
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but It was enough tweaking and solving compatibility issues for one package. I'm not going to do it again :D

Comment: @yo' And I wouldn't expect you to go through that process.  I just put it out there "because I could."

Answer (score 0):

This is a total hack, involving adding a `\beforerule` and `\afterrule` around the environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor,lipsum}

\lstset{
    backgroundcolor = \color{yellow},
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    columns = fullflexible,
    tabsize = 4,
    frame = leftline,
    framesep = 0pt,
    framexleftmargin = 3pt,
    framerule = 2pt,
    rulecolor = \color{green!50!black},
    xrightmargin = -3pt,
    numbers = left,
}
\def\beforerule{%
  \par\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
  \llap{\color{green!50!black}\rule{2pt}{3pt}}%
  \color{yellow}\rule{\dimexpr6pt+\textwidth}{3pt}}%
  \par\vspace*{-10pt}%
}
\def\afterrule{%
  \vspace*{-14.5pt}\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
  \llap{\color{green!50!black}\rule[-3pt]{2pt}{3pt}}%
  \color{yellow}\rule[-3pt]{\dimexpr6pt+\textwidth}{3pt}}%
  \par\vspace{6pt}%
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fermentum aliquam ipsum at consequat. Nam id aliquam ex, a auctor augue laoreet.

\beforerule
\begin{lstlisting}
Hello, world!

\bye
\end{lstlisting}
\afterrule

\noindent\lipsum*[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]