# Environment with optional argument based on verbatim causes strange error

Tags: verbatim

I want to define a new environment with optional argument that uses verbatim environment. My code is something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{smurf}[1][]{
  \verbatim
}{
  \endverbatim
}

This is okay:
\begin{smurf}
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
bla bla bla

This is okay, too:
\begin{smurf}[2]
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
bla bla bla

This causes a strange error:
\begin{smurf}{2}
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

The third example causes a strange error. TeX says:

```
Runaway argument?
{2}^^Mx x x x x x^^M\end{smurf}^^Mbla bla bla^^M^^M\end{document}^^M^^M
! File ended while scanning use of \verbatim@start.
```

I don't understand why it is a problem. How should I fix it?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108897/verbatim-like-environment-with-optional-arguments-poorly-behaved and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109030/optional-arguments-in-verbatim-environments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `smurf`-environment (without changing the category-code-régime) looks for an optional argument/looks for the presence of `[12` and then—after "fetching" the optional argument if present—calls `\verbatim`.

`\verbatim` in turn switches to verbatim-category-code-régime and relies on following tokens getting/being tokenized under verbatim-category-code-régime.

But with your third example the opening curly brace `{` of `{2}` is not tokenized according to verbatim-category-code-régime as it already gets tokenized under normal/unchanged category-code-régime at the time of looking for the optional argument, before `\verbatim` gets called.

Therefore at the time of executing `\verbatim` you already have a `{`-character-token of category code 1(begin group), but due to `\verbatim` switching to verbatim-category-code-régime subsequent closing curly braces won't get tokenized as category-code-2(end group)-character-tokens but will get tokenized as category-code-12(other)-character-tokens. Therefore when `\verbatim@start` gathers its argument, it finds a `{`-character-token of category code 1(begin group) but it does not find a matching `}`-character-token of category code 2(end group). This leads to a `Runaway argument?`-error.

As the category code of `[` under normal category-code-régime is the same as under verbatim-category-code-régime, you can implement a mechanism which—after switching to verbatim-category-code-régime (via `\let\do\@makeother\dospecials\@vobeyspaces\obeylines`)—does via `\kernel@ifnextchar` "look" for the presence of an `[` indicating the presence on an optional argument.

Be aware that with this approach you cannot separate the optional argument from `\begin{smurf}` by using combinations of a newline and spaces any more.

I.e.,
With

```
\begin{smurf}[optional]
```

the phrase `[optional]` is not taken for a part of the verbatim-listing but is taken for an optional argument.

With

```
\begin{smurf} [optional]
```

the phrase `⟨space⟩[optional]` is not taken for an optional argument but is taken for a part of the verbatim-listing.

With

```
\begin{smurf} 
[optional]
```

the phrase `[optional]` is not taken for an optional argument but is taken for a part of the verbatim-listing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcommand\FetchoptionalArgAndCallVerbatim[1][]{%
  The optional argument---in parentheses---is: (#1)%
  \verbatim
}%

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{smurf}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother
  \dospecials
  \@vobeyspaces
  \obeylines
  \kernel@ifnextchar[%
                    {\endgroup\FetchoptionalArgAndCallVerbatim}%
                    {\endgroup\FetchoptionalArgAndCallVerbatim[]}%
}{%
  \endverbatim
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is okay:
\begin{smurf}
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
bla bla bla

This is okay, too:
\begin{smurf}[2]
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
bla bla bla

This is okay, also:
\begin{smurf}[{\LaTeX[]}]
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
bla bla bla

This no longer causes a strange error:
\begin{smurf}{2}
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

---

The following example lets you separate the optional argument from `\begin{smurf}` with spaces.
But separating via a line-break is not implemented because this would remove the possibility of the first line of the verbatim-listing beginning with an opening square bracket `[`/this would remove the possibility of the first line of the verbatim-listing beginning with something nested in square brackets `[⟨something⟩]`.

I.e.,
With

```
\begin{smurf}[optional]
```

the phrase `[optional]` is not taken for a part of the verbatim-listing but is taken for an optional argument.

With

```
\begin{smurf} [optional]
```

the phrase `⟨space⟩[optional]` is not taken for a part of the verbatim-listing but `[optional]` is taken for an optional argument.

With

```
\begin{smurf} 
[optional]
```

the phrase `[optional]` is not taken for an optional argument but is taken for a part of the verbatim-listing.

With

```
\begin{smurf}⟨space⟩
[optional]
```

the phrase `[optional]` is not taken for an optional argument but is taken for a part of the verbatim-listing.

With

```
\begin{smurf}
⟨space⟩[optional]
```

the phrase `⟨space⟩[optional]` is not taken for an optional argument but is taken for a part of the verbatim-listing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcommand\FetchoptionalArgAndCallVerbatim[1][]{%
  The optional argument---in parentheses---is: (#1)%
  \verbatim
}%

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{smurf}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother
  \dospecials
  \@vobeyspaces
  \obeylines
  \lookaheadloop{}%
}{%
  \endverbatim
}
\begingroup
% As catcode of space will be changed, don't indent the following lines:
\@vobeyspaces%
\obeylines%
\@firstofone{% brace-level 1
\endgroup%
\newcommand\lookaheadloop[1]{% brace-level 2
\kernel@ifnextchar{ }{\gatherspace{#1}}{%  brace-level 3
\kernel@ifnextchar[%
{\endgroup\FetchoptionalArgAndCallVerbatim}%
{\endgroup\FetchoptionalArgAndCallVerbatim[]#1}%
}%  brace-level 3
}%  brace-level 2
\@ifdefinable\gatherspace{\long\def\gatherspace#1 {\lookaheadloop{#1 }}}%
}%  brace-level 1
% Now the catcode of space isn't changed any more.
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Example 1:
\begin{smurf}
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
End of example 1.

Example 2:
\begin{smurf}[2]
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
End of example 2.

Example 3:
\begin{smurf} [{\LaTeX[]}]
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
End of example 3.

Example 4:
\begin{smurf}[{\LaTeX[]}]
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
End of example 4.

Example 5:
\begin{smurf} 
[{\LaTeX[]}]
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
End of example 5.

Example 6:
\begin{smurf} 
 [{\LaTeX[]}]
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
End of example 6.

Example 7:
\begin{smurf}

[{\LaTeX[]}]
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
End of example 7.

Example 8:
\begin{smurf}{2}
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
End of example 8.

Example 9:
\begin{smurf}   {2}
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
End of example 9.

Example 10:
\begin{smurf}   
{2}
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
End of example 10.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation and code example. It suits my purposes, and seems robust against careless user inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You are forcing a lookahead to see if there is an optional argument.

After

```
\begin{smurf}{2}
```

There is no `[` so no optional argument but in looking `{` has already been seen and tokenised as a normal group starting `{`.  then the verbatim content is read and `2}` are read verbatim so there is never anything that matches the `{`.

the easiest thing to do would be to make the argument non-optional, otherwise the first token of the environment will never be read verbatim.

However you could perhaps set up the catcode of `{` earlier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{smurf}{% you need this % anyway
  \catcode`\{=12 %
  \smurfx
}{%
  \endsmurfx
}

\newenvironment{smurfx}[1][]{% you need this % anyway
  \verbatim
}{
  \endverbatim
}

This is okay:
\begin{smurf}
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
bla bla bla

This is okay, too:
\begin{smurf}[2]
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
bla bla bla

This causes a strange error:
\begin{smurf}{2}
x x x x x x
\end{smurf}
bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd not set up the catcode of `{` earlier as then you cannot use `{` and `}` any more for hiding `[` and `]` when nesting `[` and `]` within the optional argument.

Comment: @UlrichDiez well yes more that that you can't use `{` for `$\frac{a}{b}$` or any other normal tex, so it depends what use the OP had in mind for the argument, other than always discarding it.  Basically I would use the mandatory argument here as noted, the second form just does enough to explain what the issue is (but I'll +1 for your version as well:-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez well you could add `}` or do all of verbatim setup or ... (don't do this would be my real answer)