# NewDocumentEnvironment optional argument changes behaviour with \obeylines

Tags: spacing, environments, paragraphs, optional-arguments

I notice that the behaviour of environments with an optional argument that use `\obeylines` changes based on whether the optional argument is present or not.

I would have expected all the environments in the following example to look the same. But one is different.

What's going on? Is there something I can add to the definition of `bbb` to make it behave like all the others when an optional argument is present?

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{aaa}{}{\obeylines ENV:}{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{bbb}{o}{\obeylines ENV:}{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{ccc}{o}{ENV:}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{aaa}
  x
  y
\end{aaa}
\begin{bbb}
  x
  y
\end{bbb}
\begin{bbb}[arg]
  x
  y
\end{bbb}
\begin{ccc}\par
  x\par
  y\par
\end{ccc}
\begin{ccc}[arg]\par
  x\par
  y\par
\end{ccc}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: output]

Comment: Related question: [verbatim-like environment with optional arguments poorly behaved - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108897/verbatim-like-environment-with-optional-arguments-poorly-behaved) and [How to pass an optional argument to an environment with verbatim content? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/how-to-pass-an-optional-argument-to-an-environment-with-verbatim-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is "obviously" <sup>(*)</sup> that the optional argument grabber tries to tokenize the newline token, which normally has catcode 5 ("end of line") before `\obeylines` is executed which changes its catcode to 13 (active).

Since it's required to tokenize the following token to determine whether or not there is an optional argument, it's unavoidable.

(in theory it's possible to use `scantokens` to "untokenize" it. In practice, it has a performance hit and without setting `\everyeof` user might hit even more perplexing bugs & maybe confusing `\errorcontextlines` as well)

For a workaround, set the catcode of the `\endlinechar` *before*  parsing the optional argument. The cleanest way to do that at the moment (that I know of) is to define auxiliary macro/environment.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{aaa}{}{\obeylines ENV:}{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{innerbbb}{o}{ENV:}{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{bbb}{}{\obeylines\innerbbb}{\endinnerbbb}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{ccc}{o}{ENV:}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{aaa}
  x
  y
\end{aaa}
\begin{bbb}
  x
  y
\end{bbb}
\begin{bbb}[arg]
  x
  y
\end{bbb}
\begin{ccc}\par
  x\par
  y\par
\end{ccc}
\begin{ccc}[arg]\par
  x\par
  y\par
\end{ccc}
\end{document}
```

Side note, use the plain form `\innerbbb` because [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14683/250119)

Side note 2, this will make the error messages a bit confusing for runaway optional argument (i.e. you forgot to put a `]`), reporting the environment name being `innerbbb` instead of `bbb`

```
! File ended while scanning use of \environment innerbbb .
```

<sup>(*)</sup> if you're sufficiently experienced in TeX programming

Comment: (originally I made the mistake that it's not necessary to tokenize the following token, fixed now)

Comment: Actually there are "argument processors" as well, maybe there's something interesting there.

Comment: Thinking about it, the xparse code could as well use the runtime value of `@currenvir` to grab the argument, but there's a small performance hit there I think.

Comment: An alternative workaround is to add an empty mandatory argument at the end, although that makes the source code/input not as pretty..