# tcolorbox newtcblisting "! File ended while scanning use of \verbatim@start"

Tags: tcolorbox

I have the following code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{shell}[1][]{listing only, title={Output},
listing engine=minted, minted language=text}

\begin{document}

\begin{shell}
a {"John Marwood Cleese", 123456}
\end{shell}

\begin{shell}
{"John Marwood Cleese", 123456}
\end{shell}

\end{document}
```

The first shell environment can correct compiled. But the second one issued the error "`! File ended while scanning use of \verbatim@start`".

Can anyone explain this?

What I want is:

```
\begin{shell}
{"John Marwood Cleese", 123456}
\end{shell}
```

How can I get this code work? Thank you very much.

Comment: ```\begin{shell}
\ {"John Marwood Cleese", 123456}
\end{shell}``` will work, but I can explain why. It seems that ```{``` might be the troublemaker.

Comment: why `[1][]` (which is making it look for a `[` and finding `{`

Comment: You need to patch it manually if you insist on using optional argument → [How to pass an optional argument to an environment with verbatim content? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/how-to-pass-an-optional-argument-to-an-environment-with-verbatim-content) [verbatim-like environment with optional arguments poorly behaved - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108897/verbatim-like-environment-with-optional-arguments-poorly-behaved)

Comment: You're currently not using the optional argument at all. If you just remove it, everything should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you're going to use the optional argument in your real-life code, so I won't tell you to remove it.

You can use the `xparse` library. Just for the sake of experimenting, I use the optional argument to set the language.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}

\NewTCBListing{shell}{!O{text}}{
  listing only,
  title={Output},
  listing engine=minted,
  minted language=#1,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{shell}
a {"John Marwood Cleese", 123456}
\end{shell}

\begin{shell}
{"John Marwood Cleese", 123456}
\end{shell}

\begin{shell}[tex]
a {"John Marwood Cleese", 123456}
\end{shell}

\begin{shell}[tex]
{"John Marwood Cleese", 123456}
\end{shell}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `!` preceding the specification for the optional argument tells LaTeX that if a space (or endline) is found, then no optional argument will be looked for.

Limitation: you can't say `\begin{shell} [options]`: the optional argument must be attached to `}`. It doesn't seem a big deal.

The problem with `\newtcblisting{shell}[1][]{...}` is that the `[` will be looked for ignoring spaces (or the endline), so the leading `{` is already scanned before the changes for verbatim mode are performed.

Answer (score 3):

The following works by removing the optional argument. Without it there is no look-ahead for the `[` that will accidentally tokenize the `{` and freeze its category code to 1 (begin-group). Because of this category code freezing the argument grabbing for a verbatim environment doesn't work (the corresponding `\end{shell}` is part of a local group and hence hidden from TeX's delimited argument scanner).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{shell}{listing only, title={Output},
listing engine=minted, minted language=text}

\begin{document}

\begin{shell}
a {"John Marwood Cleese", 123456}
\end{shell}

\begin{shell}
{"John Marwood Cleese", 123456}
\end{shell}

\end{document}
```

If you absolutely need the optional argument you'll have a few options:

- implement the argument grabbing logic yourself
- patch some internals to get it working
- use something that doesn't hurt if it's tokenized

The following shows the last option, freezing an `\empty` that'll just expand to nothing in later steps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{shell}[1][]{listing only, title={Output},
listing engine=minted, minted language=text}

\begin{document}

\begin{shell}
a {"John Marwood Cleese", 123456}
\end{shell}

\begin{shell}
\empty{"John Marwood Cleese", 123456}
\end{shell}

\end{document}
```

But this just shows the problematic aspect of this: You'll always have to watch out to use your environment in a way that doesn't hurt. It would be better to use a mandatory argument (or at least the last argument should be a mandatory one).

Both show the following output:

[image]