# Haskell minted environement - problems with brackets

Tags: pdftex, minted

After doing some research on the interweb - I finally made the switch to minted.
As I need to document Haskell with Latex, I created the following listing according to examples found on this page. (thx btw!)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted}

\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins}

\newtcblisting{haskellcode}[1][]{
  listing engine=minted,
  colback=bg,
  colframe=black!70,
  listing only,
  minted style=colorful,
  minted language=haskell,
  minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},
  left=5mm,enhanced,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}
}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{haskellcode}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
import Yesod

data HelloWorld = HelloWorld

mkYesod "HelloWorld" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]

instance Yesod HelloWorld

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = defaultLayout [whamlet|Hello World!|]

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 HelloWorld
\end{haskellcode}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I strugle to get it to work.

```
\begin{haskellcode}
%{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
%{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
%{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
%{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
import Yesod

data HelloWorld = HelloWorld
\end{haskellcode}
```

This example works like a charm, but as soon as I remove the comment %-operator, I get tonns of errors. In my opinion there is a problem, that pdftex is trying to parse the "{}"-brackets.

Many thanks for your help :).

Martin

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The problem seems interesting, but a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is missing.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to two issues.

First, the way that `\newtcblisting` works, using it with optional arguments isn't possible. The new environment reads ahead looking for a `[` that would indicate optional arguments, but reads past the end of the line and starts reading the actual code if it doesn't find a `[`. It [is possible to capture an optional argument in such a situation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/how-to-pass-an-optional-argument-to-an-environment-with-verbatim-content), but that requires special techniques that `tcolorbox` isn't using. So if you want your environment to take *any* arguments, they will need to be mandatory (and you can always leave them empty, for example, `\begin{haskellcode}{}`).

Second, there is a bug in Pygments. The `texcomments` (`texcl`) option is causing everything after a `%{-#` at the beginning of a line to be treated as literal LaTeX code, up to the end of the line.  This means that the closing `#-}` is not properly detected. You might report this at the [Pygments site](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues). For now, the solution is not to use `texcomments` with haskell.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of G. Poole lists both problem: the *optional only* parameter for `\newtcblisting` and the Pygments bug.

For `\newtcblisting` there are two possibilites. G. Poole already explained the first one, i.e. use always at least one mandatory parameter. That is the way the `tcolorbox` package handles the `tcblisting` environment. In contrast to `tcolorbox`, this verbatim environment takes a mandatory parameter.

But there is a second possibility using `xparse`. For a *optional only* parameter, you can use the following:

```
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,xparse}

%\newtcblisting{haskellcode}[1][]{
\NewTCBListing{haskellcode}{O{}}{% <------ xparse
  listing engine=minted,
  colback=bg,
  colframe=black!70,
  listing only,
  minted style=colorful,
  minted language=haskell,
  minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},
  left=5mm,enhanced,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}
}
```

Of course, the Pygments problem still will be present, but now the `haskellcode` environment is more stable (thanks to `xparse`).