# Behavior of environment with optional argument changes when optional argument is not passed

Tags: environments, optional-arguments, fancyvrb

Recently, when I've been working with environments with an optional argument, I've noticed that the behavior changes when I introduce a set of square braces, even when there is nothing inside them. For instance:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{exer}[1][]
{
    do the following exercise from #1
    \VerbatimOut{\jobname.exer}%
}
{
    \endVerbatimOut%
    \input{\jobname.exer}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{exer}[]
some text
\end{exer}
\end{document}
```

It will compile a pdf with "some text" as well as a .exer file, but if I replace the exer environment with

```
\begin{exer}
some text
\end{exer}
```

it will throw the following error:

```
! FancyVerb Error:
  Extraneous input `some text' between \begin{exer}[<key=value>] and line end
.
\FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:
\space \space #1
}
                                                  
l.16 some text
```

So I have two questions: first, why does the environment behave differently even when I pass in the default optional argument, and second, is there any way to patch or address this behavior?

Many thanks.

Comment: Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/how-to-pass-an-optional-argument-to-an-environment-with-verbatim-content

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what would be the usefulness of this. Anyway, you have to announce `fancyvrb` that this is a `\VerbatimEnvironment`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{exer}[1][]{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  do the following exercise\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\space from~#1\fi
  \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.exer}%
}{%
  \end{VerbatimOut}%
  \par\input{\jobname.exer}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exer}[]
some text
\end{exer}

\begin{exer}[the book]
some text
\end{exer}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\makeatletter
\def\exer{\@ifnextchar[\exer@i\exer@i[]}
\def\exer@i[#1]{do the following exercise #1
\VerbatimOut{\jobname.exer}}
\def\endexer{\endVerbatimOut\par
\input{\jobname.exer}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{exer}
some text
\end{exer}
\end{document}
```