# Using the same picture over and over?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose I have a complex figure made ​​with TikZ. How do I use it several times without having to repeat all the commands?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Base figure

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue] circle (2);
  \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
    \draw[blue] (\i:1.9) -- (\i:2.1);
\end{tikzpicture}

Using base figure.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue] circle (2);
  \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
    \draw[blue] (\i:1.9) -- (\i:2.1);
  \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
    \node at (\i:2.7) {\tiny $\i^\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}

Using base figure.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue] circle (2);
  \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
    \draw[blue] (\i:1.9) -- (\i:2.1);
  \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
    \draw (0,0) -- (\i:2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Somewhat related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5338/latex-equivalent-of-context-buffers

Comment: A very complex picture could also be saved in a box register and placed using a node into the other pictures. This has a speed benefit. If you use my `storebox` package the picture is also only stored once in the output PDF.

Answer (score 32):

You could define a macro that constructs the base figure, and supply an optional argument that is added to the base figure. That allows you to use it as-is, but optionally add stuff. This abstraction promotes [consistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764) and allows for easy changes in the future:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myfigure}[1][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue] circle (2);
  \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
    \draw[blue] (\i:1.9) -- (\i:2.1);
  #1
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

Base figure

\myfigure

Using base figure.

\myfigure[%
  \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
  \node at (\i:2.7) {\tiny $\i^\circ$};%
]

Using base figure.

\myfigure[%
  \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
  \draw (0,0) -- (\i:2);%
]
\end{document}
```

You use `\myfigure` for your base figure and `\myfigure[<addition>]` for adding `<addition>` to the base figure.

Answer (score 24):

Enclose it in a `newcommand`

```
\newcommand{\bluecircle}{
    \draw[blue] circle (2);
      \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
    \draw[blue] (\i:1.9) -- (\i:2.1);
}
```

Now your final figure would be:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \bluecircle
    \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
    \draw (0,0) -- (\i:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `xsavebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xsavebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{xlrbox}{base figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[blue] circle (2);
    \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
      \draw[blue] (\i:1.9) -- (\i:2.1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{xlrbox}%
%
Base figure:

\xusebox{base figure}

Using base figure:

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {\xusebox{base figure}};
  \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
    \node at (\i:2.7) {\tiny $\i^\circ$};%
\end{tikzpicture}%

Using base figure again:

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {\xusebox{base figure}};
  \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
    \draw (0,0) -- (\i:2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should leave out `\begin{tikzpicture}` from `base figure` to avoid nested environments

Comment: It is not nested. The base figure is distilled into a PDF XObject and a reference is later inserted by `\xusebox`. There is no interference possible.

Comment: Ops, my apologies, I forgot that this is the functionality of `xsavebox`.

Comment: No problem at all. Thanks for your interest ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A variation of the answers using the package `scontents`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[store-env=figbase]{scontents}
\begin{document}
Store Base figure

\begin{scontents}
  \draw[blue] circle (2);
  \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
    \draw[blue] (\i:1.9) -- (\i:2.1);
\end{scontents}
% print fig base
\begin{tikzpicture}
\getstored[1]{figbase}
\end{tikzpicture}

Using base figure.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \getstored[1]{figbase}
  \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
    \node at (\i:2.7) {\tiny $\i^\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}

Using base figure.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \getstored[1]{figbase}
  \foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
    \draw (0,0) -- (\i:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```