# Is there a way to use a previous TikZ picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming

Let's say I spend some time drawing this picture:

[image]

And after a few paragraphs I want to draw the same picture plus some "spices".

Of course I could just copy-and-paste the code, then edit the few things I want to change. But this turn the LaTeX code messy, as my figure repeats over and over!

**Question**

How could I use the previous code of a `tikzpicture` without copying it over and over?

*NOTE*: There is no caption!

Comment: This question is very similar to [Using the same picture over and over?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34886/5764) The idea is to use a macro-form of the image, so you can re-use it with some "spices" at a later stage. Does it answer your question? If so, we can close this as a duplicate. If not, give some feedback.