# How to use active characters in environs \BODY

Tags: environments, catcodes

I Kong that it’s impossible to [have verbatim content in `\BODY`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51239/4918) but is it possible to use an active character at least?

I define `<x>` as a shortcut for `\fbox{x}` and would like to be able to activate this with `\activebox`. Generally it works fine in normal environments and even if I use a wrapper but not if the activation is done directly in an `environ` environment.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\begingroup
\catcode`< = \active
\gdef<#1>{
   \fbox{#1}
}
\endgroup
\def\activatebox{
   \catcode`<=\active
}

\NewEnviron{test}{
   \begin{itemize}
   \BODY
   \end{itemize}
}

\newenvironment{testwrapper}[1]{
   #1
   \test
} {
   \endtest
}

\begin{document}
   Test <Box>

   \begin{itemize}
      \activatebox
      \item Test <Box>
   \end{itemize}

   \begin{test}
      \activatebox
      \item Test <Box>
   \end{test}

   \begin{testwrapper}{\activatebox}
      \item Test <Box>
   \end{testwrapper}
\end{document}
```

---

In my real example it is of curse a bit more complicated: The `\BODY` is printed out in the document and also written to a file. I can’t use `\lst@BeginWriteFile` here because there is a single file saving multiple `\BODY`s. Here’s the original definition of my environment:

**More context MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ,xparse, etoolbox}

\begingroup
\catcode`< = \active
\gdef<#1>{
   \fbox{#1}
}
\endgroup
\def\activatebox{
   \catcode`<=\active
}

\ExplSyntaxOn% ============================================================

\bool_new:N \tobi_in_group_of_boxes_bool
\bool_set_false:N \tobi_in_group_of_boxes_bool

\NewDocumentCommand { \mybox } { m } {
   \fbox { #1 }
   \bool_if:NF \tobi_in_group_of_boxes_bool {
   \iow_shipout_x:Nx \tobi_solutions_iow {
      \tl_to_str:n { \boxline }
         { \exp_not:n { \exp_not:N #1 } }
         { \exp_not:N \thepage }
   }
   }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_shipout:Nn { No }

\NewEnviron { boxgroup } {
   \bool_set_true:N \tobi_in_group_of_boxes_bool
   \iow_shipout_x:Nx \tobi_solutions_iow {
      \tl_to_str:n { \begin { boxgroup } } { \exp_not:N \thepage }
   }
   \iow_shipout:No \tobi_solutions_iow { \BODY }
   \iow_shipout_x:Nx \tobi_solutions_iow {
      \tl_to_str:n { \end { boxgroup } }
   }
   \par\textsf{\color{black!35}GROUP~START}\par
   \BODY
   \par\textsf{\color{black!35}GROUP~END}\par
}

\iow_new:N \tobi_solutions_iow
\iow_open:Nn \tobi_solutions_iow { \c_sys_jobname_str . boxes }
\AfterEndDocument {
   \iow_close:N \tobi_solutions_iow
}

\ExplSyntaxOff% ============================================================

\begin{document}
   Test <Box A> \mybox{Box B}

   \begin{itemize}
      \activatebox
      \item Test <Box C>
   \end{itemize}

   \begin{boxgroup}
      \activatebox
      Test <Box D>
   \end{boxgroup}

   \activatebox% must be part of the *.boxes file, thus can’t be
   % outside of the environment
   \begin{boxgroup}
      Test <Box E>
   \end{boxgroup}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to make the char active *before* the `eniron`ment grabs its body (= reads its argument which fixes catcodes): `\activatebox\begin{test} \item Test <Box> \end{test}`. Your `testwrapper` actually shows this nicely…

Comment: @clemens: I know, but I hoped that there is a way or working around this. E.g. hooking into environ somehow to check wether `<` is active or not. The problem with activating it outside the env (or in a wrapper) is that `\activebox` isn’t written to the file, which it has to be. (With the wrapper this would be possible, but I’d prefer a more elegant solution …

Comment: `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn` might help you

Comment: @clemens: Hm … in that case I’d have to test within the environment body if `\activateboxes` is present and then do the rescan, however that won’t work if `\activateboxes` should be usable somewhere mid environment. I just tried \tl_rescan:nx { \activateboxed } { \BODY }, but it didn’t work.

Comment: It works if I define new environment with the activation build in (see edited OP).

Comment: Unrelated code snippets. `:(`

Comment: @egreg: I’m sorry … I hoped that the MWE would be enough to illustrate the root of the problem. The code snippets should just provide some context. But I added another MWE providing more context :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute something to `<` when it's time to typeset the contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{environ,xparse, etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobi_active_less:w #1 >
 {
  \fbox{#1}
 }
\char_set_active_eq:NN < \tobi_active_less:w
\NewDocumentCommand{\activatebox}{}
 {
  \char_set_catcode_active:N <
  \bool_set_true:N \l_tobi_active_less_bool
 }

\cs_new:Npn \tobi_perhaps_active_less:
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l_tobi_active_less_bool { \tobi_active_less:w } { < }
 }

\bool_new:N \l_tobi_active_less_bool
\bool_new:N \l_tobi_in_group_of_boxes_bool
\bool_set_false:N \l_tobi_in_group_of_boxes_bool

\NewDocumentCommand { \mybox } { m }
 {
  \fbox { #1 }
  \bool_if:NF \l_tobi_in_group_of_boxes_bool
   {
    \iow_shipout:Nx \tobi_solutions_iow
     {
      \exp_not:n { \boxline{#1} } { \thepage }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_shipout:Nn { NV }

\NewEnviron { boxgroup }
 {
  \bool_set_true:N \l_tobi_in_group_of_boxes_bool
  \iow_shipout:Nx \tobi_solutions_iow
   {
    \exp_not:N \begin{boxgroup}{\thepage}
   }
   \iow_shipout:NV \tobi_solutions_iow \BODY
   \iow_shipout:Nn \tobi_solutions_iow
    {
     \end{boxgroup}
    }
   \par\textsf{\color{black!35}GROUP~START}\par
   \tl_replace_all:Nnn \BODY { < } { \tobi_perhaps_active_less: }
   \BODY
   \par\textsf{\color{black!35}GROUP~END}\par
 }

\iow_new:N \tobi_solutions_iow
\iow_open:Nn \tobi_solutions_iow { \c_sys_jobname_str . boxes }
\AfterEndDocument
 {
  \iow_close:N \tobi_solutions_iow
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test <Box A> \mybox{Box B}

\begin{itemize}
  \activatebox
  \item Test <Box C>
\end{itemize}

\begin{boxgroup}
  \activatebox
  Test <Box D>
\end{boxgroup}

\mybox{Abc\textbf{def}}

\end{document}
```

This is what will be written in the `.boxes` file; note I changed the code so that `\thepage` gets expanded, which your code doesn't.

```
\boxline {Box B}{1}
\begin {boxgroup}{1}
\activatebox Test <Box D>
\end {boxgroup}
\boxline {Abc\textbf {def}}{1}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine.     //     Why do you say, that in my code `\thepage` is unexpanded? It seems to work in my code as I use `\iow_shipout_x:Nx`, thus `\theblanknumber` is immediately expanded but the expansion of `\thepage` is delayed until the shipout to make sure I get the correct number. At least that’s my plan and I couldn’t find a problem when testing.

Comment: @Tobi `\iow_shipout:Nn` is simpler anyway.

Comment: Yeah, but while testing I had the problem that in that case the pagenumber wasn’t always correct, that why I switched to `\iow_shipout_x`

Comment: I found a problem with your code, if the environment contains `Test <Box D> $x = <5> = \frac{<10>}{<2>}$` it doesn’t work in the `\frac` parts …

Comment: @Tobi No, but I'm not clairvoyant. You need `l3regex` if you want to do the substitution at any nesting level.

Comment: Sorry I din’t thought about the nesting level. It works fine with `\regex_replace_all:nnN { < } { \c{pirkl_perhaps_active_less:} } \BODY`

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do something along the following lines (not knowing what the final goal will be):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ,xparse,etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobi_frame_box:w #1 > { \fbox {#1} }
\char_set_active_eq:NN < \tobi_frame_box:w


\tl_new:N \l__tobi_tmpa_tl
\bool_new:N \l_tobi_in_group_of_boxes_bool
\bool_set_false:N \l_tobi_in_group_of_boxes_bool

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobi_handle_boxgroup:n #1
  {
    \bool_set_true:N \l_tobi_in_group_of_boxes_bool
    \iow_shipout_x:Nx \l_tobi_solutions_iow {
      \tl_to_str:n { \begin { boxgroup } } { \exp_not:N \thepage }
    }
    \iow_shipout:Nn \l_tobi_solutions_iow {#1}
    \iow_shipout_x:Nx \l_tobi_solutions_iow {
      \tl_to_str:n { \end { boxgroup } }
    }
    \par\textsf{\color{black!35}GROUP~START}\par
    #1
    \par\textsf{\color{black!35}GROUP~END}\par
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobi_handle_boxgroup:n {V}

\NewEnviron {boxgroup} {
  \tl_set_rescan:NnV \l__tobi_tmpa_tl
    { \char_set_catcode_active:N < }
    \BODY
  \tobi_handle_boxgroup:V \l__tobi_tmpa_tl
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set_rescan:Nnn {NnV}

\iow_new:N \l_tobi_solutions_iow
\iow_open:Nn \l_tobi_solutions_iow { \c_sys_jobname_str . boxes }
\AfterEndDocument {
  \iow_close:N \l_tobi_solutions_iow
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{boxgroup}
  Test <Box D>
\end{boxgroup}

\begin{boxgroup}
  Test <Box E>
\end{boxgroup}

\end{document}
```

### `test.boxes`

```
\begin {boxgroup}{1}
Test <Box D>
\end {boxgroup}
\begin {boxgroup}{1}
Test <Box E>
\end {boxgroup}
```

### document

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your example. But as far as I can see in that case the active character is hard wired in the definition of `{boxgroup}`, while I’d like a version where I can use `\activateboxes` inside the environment to decide wether `<` is active or not.