# Using \verb and \begin{verbatim} / \end{verbatim} in NewEnviron

Tags: environments, itemize, verbatim

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{myitemize} {
\show\BODY
\begin{itemize}
\BODY
\end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \verb|test|
\end{itemize}

\begin{myitemize}
\item \verb|test|
\end{myitemize}

\end{document}
```

The first list works, but the second one throws Latex errors (missing } inserted, extra }, \verb illegal ...). It has probably something to do with the way NewEnviron collects it's body but can someone elaborate on this problem.

Log file shows:

```
> \BODY=macro:
->\item \verb |test|.
```

so why is there a problem? And of course, what is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is similar to passing `\verb` as an argument to a macro, as in

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{#1}

\mymacro{\verb|test|}
```

Your solution in this case would be to not use [`environ`](//ctan.org/pkg/environ):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{myitemize}
  {\begin{itemize}}
  {\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \verb|test|
\end{itemize}

\begin{myitemize}
  \item \verb|test|
\end{myitemize}

\end{document}
```

Why is there a problem to start with? The collection of content fixes the category codes - something `\verb` and `verbatim` needs access to (or change) in order to function properly.

Comment: well, I want to collect the body to patch particular code strings and pass the result on to itemize.

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw: Does your code string contain particularly odd characters?

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw: Try [this](https://pastebin.com/0LZ2Pyse). It works, partially...

Comment: It looks promising...

Comment: For now. I will do with `\renewenvironment{verbatim}[1]{\begingroup\ttfamily #1}{\endgroup}`

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51239/verbatim-in-environ-s-body

Comment: I wanted to use a `\colorbox` on the verbatim. How to do that? All it does is throw errors at me.

Comment: @Someone: You can store the verbatim content in a box, and then place the box inside a `\colorbox`.