# How to delete a command in the \BODY macro of environment defined by \NewEnviron

Tags: environments, definition

My environment defined by `\NewEnviron` macro contains a macro `\mymacro`. How can to delete the macro `\mymacro` in the `\BODY` macro, when it executes?

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewEnviron{myenviron}{\newcommand\mymacro[2]{\def\textone{##1}}{\def\texttwo{##2}}} \gdef\result{\BODY}}
\begin{document}
\begin{myenviron}
Some text here
\mymacro{Textone}{Texttwo}
\end{myenviron}
\end{document}
```

How can I delete the `\mymacro` in the `\result` macro? I have try by many ways, but I cannot!

Now I want to add more detail my problem so that the experts can help me.

I have a lot of multiple choice questions in of the following structure:

```
\begin{myenviron}
Question
\choice{\True First answer}{Second answer}{Third answer}{Fourth answer}
\sulution{The detail solution.}
\end{myenviron}
```

Here `\True` means that is the correct answer.

I want to convert to the `multi` environment of the moodle package to upload to my moodle website.

I have tried to do as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[final]{moodle}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xstring}
\moodleregisternewcommands

\makeatletter
\newcounter{c@ex}%
\newcounter{ans@wer}%
\newcounter{correct@answer}%
\newcommand{\True}{}%
\newcommand\exname{MC}
%%define the command to hide the text body of the environment.
\newlength{\trashlength}%
\def\hide@text#1{%
    \settowidth{\trashlength}{#1}
}
%%define the command to find the correct answer.
\def\begin@ans{\@ifnextchar\True
{\setcounter{correct@answer}{\theans@wer}}{\stepcounter{ans@wer}}%
}
\environbodyname\@body
\htmlregister\@body

\NewEnviron{myenviron}{%
    \stepcounter{c@ex}
    \setcounter{ans@wer}{1}
}%
\AtEndEnvironment{myenviron}{%
    \newcommand{\choice}[4]{
        \newcommand{\ansone}{#1}\hide@text{\begin@ans #1}
        \newcommand{\anstwo}{#2}\hide@text{\begin@ans #2}
        \newcommand{\ansthree}{#3}\hide@text{\begin@ans #3}
        \newcommand{\ansfour}{#4}\hide@text{\begin@ans #4}}%
    \newcommand{\solution}[1]{\newcommand{\feed@back}{#1}}%
    \hide@text{\xa\global\xa\def\xa\result\xa{\@body}}
\ifnum\the\value{correct@answer}=1%
    \begin{multi}[numbering=ABCD,penalty=0,feedback={\feed@back}]{\exname\thec@ex}          
            \@body
            \item* \ansone%
            \item \anstwo%
            \item \ansthree%
            \item \ansfour%
    \end{multi}
\else
\ifnum\the\value{correct@answer}=2%
    \begin{multi}[numbering=ABCD,penalty=0,feedback={\feed@back}]{\exname\thec@ex}
            \@body
            \item \ansone%
            \item* \anstwo%
            \item \ansthree%
            \item \ansfour%
    \end{multi}
\else
\ifnum\the\value{correct@answer}=3
    \begin{multi}[numbering=ABCD,penalty=0,feedback={\feed@back}]{\exname\thec@ex}
            \@body
            \item \ansone%
            \item \anstwo%
            \item* \ansthree%
            \item \ansfour%
    \end{multi}
\else
\ifnum\the\value{correct@answer}=4
    \begin{multi}[numbering=ABCD,penalty=0,feedback={\feed@back}]{\exname\thec@ex}
            \@body
            \item \ansone%
            \item \anstwo%
            \item \ansthree%
            \item* \ansfour%    
    \end{multi}
\else
\relax
\fi
\fi
\fi
\fi
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{My first test}
\begin{myenviron}
This is my question.

\choice
{\True Answer one}
{Answer two}
{Answer three}
{Answer four}
\solution{This is a detail answer.}
\end{myenviron}

\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

It work fine and output correctly in pdf file. However, in .xml file, the body contains the `\choice` and `\solution` macros. This is the body containing in .xml file:

```
<text><![CDATA[<p>This is my question. <BR/> \newcommand {Answer one}{Answer one}\hide@text {\begin@ans Answer one} \newcommand {Answer two}{Answer two}\hide@text {\begin@ans Answer two} \newcommand {Answer three}{Answer three}\hide@text {\begin@ans Answer three} \newcommand {Answer four}{Answer four}\hide@text {\begin@ans Answer four} \newcommand {This is a detail answer.}{This is a detail answer.}</p>]]></text>
```

while I need only `This is my question`.

Comment: Please extend your example to a proper document (there is no document class)

Comment: Whatdo you want to delete? just `\mymacro` or all of `\mymacro{Textone}{Texttwo}` ? do you want `\textone` and `\texttwo` to be defined? (they will not be if you delete `\mymacro`?)

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to delete a macro that's about to become undefined anyway.  How do you know it isn't being deleted?

Comment: @Teepeemm I guess the OP wants to use `\result` after the environment but it's not at all clear what that definition should be

Comment: First of all, you need `\xdef\result{\BODY}` (plus removing some extra braces).  `\BODY` is undefined outside the environment.  Note that `\textone` and `\texttwo` are local and wil be lost.

Comment: I have a data base with many data in the structure of `myenviron`. I want to convert them to another environment or write to a .tex file in subtable structure. So I want the `Some text here` of the environment, because it is easy to catch the \textone and \texttwo by set the global macros.

Comment: So you want `\result` to contain only that? What should the output of the actual environment be and what are the other definitions supposed to do?

Comment: What does your database look like?  There are packages that specialize in working with csv files.  It's still not clear what you're wanting to happen.

Comment: I have a database of the multiple choice questions that the question is of the structure `\begin{myenviron} Question.... \choice{first answer}{\True second answer}{third answer}{fourth answer}  \solution{The detail solution} \end{myenviron}`.  I want to convert them to the structure of `multi` environment of moodle package.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51239/verbatim-in-environ-s-body

Comment: Can you edit your question to show, more specifically to your application, what `myenviron` looks like to begin with and what you would like it to have looked like, given the appropriate processing?