# The display math mode and the `center` environment

Tags: math-mode, macros, environments

I have asked a question at [How to delete a command in the \BODY macro of environment defined by \NewEnviron](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694632/how-to-delete-a-command-in-the-body-macro-of-environment-defined-by-newenviron) about the problem when I try to convert my `ex` environment to the `multi` environment of moodle package.

I have tried to solve my problem since last weekend, and now, I have solved almost everything. It works fine and give output .pdf file and .xml file correct result.

However, it takes errors with display math mode `$$...$$` and `\[...\]` and `\begin{center}...\end{center}` environment.

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{moodle}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,yhmath,mathrsfs,fontawesome}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,enumerate,tkz-euclide,tikz-3dplot,tikz,tkz-tab}
\moodleregisternewcommands

\makeatletter
\newcounter{c@ex}%
\setcounter{c@ex}{0}
\newcounter{ans@wer}%
\newcounter{correct@answer}%
\newcommand{\True}{}%
\newcommand\exname{MC}
%% Define the command to hide the text body of the environment.
\newlength{\trashlength}%
\def\hide@text#1{%
    \settowidth{\trashlength}{#1}
}
%% Define the command to find the correct answer.
\def\begin@ans{\@ifnextchar\True
{\setcounter{correct@answer}{\theans@wer}}{\stepcounter{ans@wer}}%
}
\environbodyname\@body
\htmlregister\@body
\htmlregister\final@result
\htmlregister\ans@one
\htmlregister\ans@two
\htmlregister\ans@three
\htmlregister\ans@four
\htmlregister\feed@back
\htmlregister\envbody
\newcommand{\choice}[4]{
    \gdef\ans@one{#1}
    \gdef\ans@two{#2}
    \gdef\ans@three{#3}
    \gdef\ans@four{#4}
    \gdef\del@choice{\choice
    {#1}
    {#2}
    {#3}
    {#4}
    }%
}%
\newcommand{\loigiai}[1]{
    \gdef\feed@back{#1}
    \gdef\del@feedback{\loigiai{#1}}
}%
\NewEnviron{ex}{%
}%
\AtEndEnvironment{ex}{%
    \stepcounter{c@ex}
    \hide@text{\@body}
%% Delete the macro \choice and \loigiai in the body of environment
    \hide@text{
        \global\let\@result\@body
        \expandarg
        \StrDel{\@result}{\del@choice}[\re@sult]
        \StrDel{\re@sult}{\del@feedback}[\re@@sult]
        \global\let\final@result\re@@sult
    }
%   \let\envbody\noexpand{\funal@result}
%% Finding the correct answer
\setcounter{ans@wer}{1}
\hide@text{\expandafter\begin@ans\ans@one}
\hide@text{\expandafter\begin@ans\ans@two}
\hide@text{\expandafter\begin@ans\ans@three}
\hide@text{\expandafter\begin@ans\ans@four}
%% Write the data in `milti' environment
\def\ex@name{\exname\thec@ex}
\ifnum\the\value{correct@answer}=1%
    \begin{multi}[numbering=ABCD,penalty=0,feedback={\feed@back}]{\ex@name}         
            \final@result
            \item* \ans@one%
            \item \ans@two%
            \item \ans@three%
            \item \ans@four%
    \end{multi}
\else
\ifnum\the\value{correct@answer}=2%
    \begin{multi}[numbering=ABCD,penalty=0,feedback={\feed@back}]{\exname\thec@ex}
            \final@result
            \item \ans@one%
            \item* \ans@two%
            \item \ans@three%
            \item \ans@four%
    \end{multi}
\else
\ifnum\the\value{correct@answer}=3
    \begin{multi}[numbering=ABCD,penalty=0,feedback={\feed@back}]{\exname\thec@ex}
            \final@result
            \item \ans@one%
            \item \ans@two%
            \item* \ans@three%
            \item \ans@four%
    \end{multi}
\else
\ifnum\the\value{correct@answer}=4
    \begin{multi}[numbering=ABCD,penalty=0,feedback={\feed@back}]{\exname\thec@ex}
            \final@result
            \item \ans@one%
            \item \ans@two%
            \item \ans@three%
            \item* \ans@four%   
    \end{multi}
\else
\relax
\fi
\fi
\fi
\fi
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{My first test}
\begin{ex}
This is my question. $\dfrac{a}{b}$

\choice
{\True Answer one}
{Answer two}
{Answer three}
{Answer four}
\loigiai{This is a detail answer.}
\end{ex}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

I don't know where is wrong, when I use display math mode in the body of my question I get errors (of course it is used right syntax)

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
```

In addition, when I use \begin{center}...\end{center} I get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

Please help me to fix them!

Comment: So, avoid `\[..\]` (and `$$...$$`) and instead use `$...$`. Use `\centering` instead of `center` environment.  Thus, `\centering $...$` will give a centered equation.

Comment: `%% Define the command to hide the text body of the environment.` that is not what `\hide@text` does, it typesets a space, and sets a length register, and gives errors on vertical material like a paragraph or display math. why do you need to measure the width????

Comment: using `c@ex` as a counter name is not exactly wrong but rather confusing as latex uses `c@` as a prefix for count registers, so `\newcounter{ex}` allocates `\c@ex` and `\newcounter{c@ex}`  allocates `\c@c@ex`

Answer (score 4):

You could simplify your example to

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\mbox{$ \times $}

\mbox{$$ \times $$}

\mbox{\begin{center} x \end{center}}

\end{document}
```

Where you get no error from `$` but `$$` produces

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.7 \mbox{$$ \times $$}
                       
?
```

because in an hbox `$$` is like `$ $` and makes an empty math list so `\times` is not in math mode, it is in the text between two empty math lists.

and `center` produces

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \mbox{\begin{center} x \end{center}}
                                        
?
```

as you can not have a vertical display construct in a horizontal box.

---

So you definitely do not want

```
%% Define the command to hide the text body of the environment.
\newlength{\trashlength}%
\def\hide@text#1{%
    \settowidth{\trashlength}{#1}
}
```

which acts like `\mbox` and is the cause of the errors, you probably do not want `\StrDel` either. You do not say anywhere what you want this code to do, and I can not guess, so this answer is restricted to explaining why you get errors, I can't suggest alternative code.

Comment: as my question before https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694632/how-to-delete-a-command-in-the-body-macro-of-environment-defined-by-newenviron, I have available data of the structure of `ex` environment. I want to convert them to the structure of `multi` environment of the moodle package. In the code you mentioned above I want to call the `\@body` to execute command `\choice` and `\loigiai` but I don't want to show the content of it. After that, I use `\StrDel` to delete `\choice` and `\loigiai` from `\@body` since I don't want to show them in the .xml file.

Comment: as your pointed out, It make errors because I call `\@body` in `\hide@text` like `\mbox`. How can I call and execute the macro `\@body` but to not show it output?

Comment: @phchon you could use `\setbox\@tempboxa\vbox{{\@body}}` with vbox and two brace groups but I doubt you need this at all.

Comment: @phchon why don't you simply give the commands suitable definitions for moodle, I can't see any reason for \StrDel or discarding boxes, but you haven't anywhere mentioned in the question the xml format being written. leaving people to reverse engineer the requirement by running the output.

Comment: With `\vbox`, the display math mode works fine, but it also makes error with `\begin{center}...\end{center}` environment.

Comment: @phchon it would not error if you could use `center` there without the box, but you could reset more with `\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\@body\end{minipage}}` or better, remove the boxing

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in a comment, avoid `\[..\]` (and `$$...$$`) in this context and instead use `$...$`. Use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment. Thus, `\centering $...$` will give a centered equation (you can use braces, `{\centering $...$\par}`, if you need to limit the scope of the centering).

You may or may not desire to add `\displaystyle` to the beginning of the equation material, if you wish to further emulate the display-style appearance otherwise provided by `\[...\]`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{moodle}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,yhmath,mathrsfs,fontawesome}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,enumerate,tkz-euclide,tikz-3dplot,tikz,tkz-tab}
\moodleregisternewcommands

\makeatletter
\newcounter{c@ex}%
\setcounter{c@ex}{0}
\newcounter{ans@wer}%
\newcounter{correct@answer}%
\newcommand{\True}{}%
\newcommand\exname{MC}
%% Define the command to hide the text body of the environment.
\newlength{\trashlength}%
\def\hide@text#1{%
    \settowidth{\trashlength}{#1}
}
%% Define the command to find the correct answer.
\def\begin@ans{\@ifnextchar\True
{\setcounter{correct@answer}{\theans@wer}}{\stepcounter{ans@wer}}%
}
\environbodyname\@body
\htmlregister\@body
\htmlregister\final@result
\htmlregister\ans@one
\htmlregister\ans@two
\htmlregister\ans@three
\htmlregister\ans@four
\htmlregister\feed@back
\htmlregister\envbody
\newcommand{\choice}[4]{
    \gdef\ans@one{#1}
    \gdef\ans@two{#2}
    \gdef\ans@three{#3}
    \gdef\ans@four{#4}
    \gdef\del@choice{\choice
    {#1}
    {#2}
    {#3}
    {#4}
    }%
}%
\newcommand{\loigiai}[1]{
    \gdef\feed@back{#1}
    \gdef\del@feedback{\loigiai{#1}}
}%
\NewEnviron{ex}{%
}%
\AtEndEnvironment{ex}{%
    \stepcounter{c@ex}
    \hide@text{\@body}
%% Delete the macro \choice and \loigiai in the body of environment
    \hide@text{
        \global\let\@result\@body
        \expandarg
        \StrDel{\@result}{\del@choice}[\re@sult]
        \StrDel{\re@sult}{\del@feedback}[\re@@sult]
        \global\let\final@result\re@@sult
    }
%   \let\envbody\noexpand{\funal@result}
%% Finding the correct answer
\setcounter{ans@wer}{1}
\hide@text{\expandafter\begin@ans\ans@one}
\hide@text{\expandafter\begin@ans\ans@two}
\hide@text{\expandafter\begin@ans\ans@three}
\hide@text{\expandafter\begin@ans\ans@four}
%% Write the data in `milti' environment
\def\ex@name{\exname\thec@ex}
\ifnum\the\value{correct@answer}=1%
    \begin{multi}[numbering=ABCD,penalty=0,feedback={\feed@back}]{\ex@name}         
            \final@result
            \item* \ans@one%
            \item \ans@two%
            \item \ans@three%
            \item \ans@four%
    \end{multi}
\else
\ifnum\the\value{correct@answer}=2%
    \begin{multi}[numbering=ABCD,penalty=0,feedback={\feed@back}]{\exname\thec@ex}
            \final@result
            \item \ans@one%
            \item* \ans@two%
            \item \ans@three%
            \item \ans@four%
    \end{multi}
\else
\ifnum\the\value{correct@answer}=3
    \begin{multi}[numbering=ABCD,penalty=0,feedback={\feed@back}]{\exname\thec@ex}
            \final@result
            \item \ans@one%
            \item \ans@two%
            \item* \ans@three%
            \item \ans@four%
    \end{multi}
\else
\ifnum\the\value{correct@answer}=4
    \begin{multi}[numbering=ABCD,penalty=0,feedback={\feed@back}]{\exname\thec@ex}
            \final@result
            \item \ans@one%
            \item \ans@two%
            \item \ans@three%
            \item* \ans@four%   
    \end{multi}
\else
\relax
\fi
\fi
\fi
\fi
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{My first test}
\begin{ex}
\centering This is my question. $\dfrac{a}{b}$

 $\dfrac{c}{d}$
\choice
{\True Answer one}
{Answer two}
{Answer three}
{Answer four}
\loigiai{This is a detail answer.}
\end{ex}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know we can use `$...$` and `\centering` instead of `$$...$$` or `\[...\]`  but the moodle package only provides output the `center` environment  in .xml file for uploading in moodle website. Therefore, we need to fix the problems and use `center` environment and display math mode.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, all you need to do is to transform your input structure to the input structure that `moodle` expects. **Here I am assuming that your input data always have the structure**

```
\begin{ex}
  Question text
  \choice{...}{...}{...}{...}
  \loigiai{...}
\end{ex}
```

**(in particular, the `\choice` always appears after "Question Text", and `\loigiai` always appears last, and every question has a `\loigiai` command (the feedback isn't optional).)**

In this case, if you define `ex` using a `\NewEnviron`, you can parse `\BODY` with a delimited macro of the form

```
\long\def\@transformBody#1\choice#2#3#4#5\loigiai#6{...}
```

in which `#1` becomes the question text, `#2...#5` are the choices, and `#6` is the feedback. One can try to just perform a suitable transformation and stuff things into `\begin{multi}...\end{multi}`, but since the latter is also built from a `\NewEnviron`, we can also cut-out the middleman and just copy the definition of `multi` with the appropriate things thrown in.

There is however one last problem: your original format marks the correct answer with `\True` and moodle uses `*`. Here I make another assumption: **you always put `\True` at the beginning of the answer**. Basically, I want to be able to expand `\True` to become `*` without impacting the rest of the choice text; this is easy to do for the first token in a list.

*Remark: there may be other considerations I haven't thought off, but at least for basic test cases the following works. Some explanations are included in-line*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{moodle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand\True{*} %% Makes \True expand to *

\makeatletter
%%%%
\long\def\@transformBody#1\choice#2#3#4#5\loigiai#6{%
        %% The purpose of the next four lines are to expand the first token
        %% of the answer choices, so that \True -> *
        \ExpandArgs{Nf}\def\my@choice@A{#2}
        \ExpandArgs{Nf}\def\my@choice@B{#3}
        \ExpandArgs{Nf}\def\my@choice@C{#4}
        \ExpandArgs{Nf}\def\my@choice@D{#5}
        %% The next command creates the processed body text to pass on for
        %% processing by Moodle's internal commands. The complicated 
        %% string of \expandafter's are all because of the \True -> * replacement
        \long\edef\ex@NewBody{\unexpanded{#1}
                \noexpand\item\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\my@choice@A}
                \noexpand\item\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\my@choice@B}
                \noexpand\item\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\my@choice@C}
                \noexpand\item\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\my@choice@D}}%
        %% This stashes the feedback somewhere
        \def\ex@feedback{#6}%
}
\newcounter{mymulti}
\NewEnviron{ex}{%
        \refstepcounter{mymulti}
        \expandafter\@transformBody\BODY   %Process the \BODY
    \bgroup
      \setkeys{moodle}{numbering=ABCD,penalty=0,feedback={\ex@feedback},questionname={MC\themymulti}}% Sets most of the Moodle parameters for the MC question
      \global\advance\moodle@totalmarks by \csname moodle@default grade\endcsname pt
      \expandafter\gatheritems\xa{\ex@NewBody}% Feed the Moodle Processor the transformed body text
      %% everything below is copied straight from the definition of the 
      %% multi environment in moodle.sty
      \let\moodle@questionheader=\gatheredheader
      %First, the LaTeX processing
      \item \moodle@begin@samepage \textbf{\moodle@questionname}
      \ifmoodle@handout
        \moodle@makelatextag@qtype{multi}
      \else
        \moodle@latex@writetags
        \par
        \noindent
        \moodle@makelatextag@qtype{multi}%
        \moodle@makelatextag@value{default grade}{marked out of}
        \moodle@makelatextag@value{penalty}{penalty}%
      \fi
      \moodle@makelatextag@multi\par
      \noindent
      \moodle@questionheader
      \edef\moodle@generalfeedback{\expandonce\moodle@feedback}
      \csname moodle@multi@latexprocessing\endcsname
      \moodle@end@samepage
      %Now, writing information to XML
      \@moodle@ifgeneratexml{%
        \xa\questiontext\xa{\moodle@questionheader}% Save the question text.
        \csname writemultiquestion\endcsname
        \bgroup
          \gdef\moodle@answers@xml{}%
          \setkeys{moodle}{feedback={}}%
          \xa\loopthroughitemswithcommand\xa{\csname savemultianswer\endcsname}%
          \passvalueaftergroup{\moodle@answers@xml}%
        \egroup
        \moodle@writeanswers%
        \moodle@writetags%
        \writetomoodle{</question>}%
      }{}%
    \egroup
}%

%%%%






\makeatother

\moodleregisternewcommands


\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{A}
\begin{ex}
This is my question. $\dfrac{a}{b}$

\choice
{\True Answer one}
{$15$ Answer two}
{Answer three}
{Answer four}
\loigiai{This is a detail answer.}
\end{ex}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a new idea for me thinking carefully about my problem!

Comment: I have read the moodle.sty file but I cannot find the counter to count the number of questions in a quiz. Do you know which is the counter? Please, let me know the counter!

Comment: It is just an enumerate. (More precisely, `\begin{quiz}` ends by [essentially] opening up a `\begin{enumerate}`. And each question (e.g. `\begin{multi}`) writes a `\item` as the first thing it does. So the numbering is controlled by `enumi` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks you are right!