# Where is the definition of the math mod environment `$$...$$`?

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, definition

I have a problem with display math modes `$$...$$` and `\[...\]`, see [The display math mode and the `center` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695023/the-display-math-mode-and-the-center-environment). So, I want to find the definition of the display math mode `$$...$$` for understading it clearly. However, I can't find where is the definition of the display math mode.

Please, let me know, where is the definition of the display math mode `$$...$$`?

Comment: `$$` is a TeX primitive. See [Why is \\[ ... \\] preferable to $$ ... $$?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/503). `\[` is defined in the LaTeX kernel, (`texdoc source2e` to see its definition) and redefined by `amsmath` if you are loading that package.

Answer (score 7):

`$$` is defined in the source code of tex, it is not a latex-defined environment. Any two characters of catcode 3 start display math.

The source is written in web (pascal)

tex.web is available from ctan

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/tex

Here is the part that scans for `$` or `$$` to enter inline or display math.

```
@ We get into math mode from horizontal mode when a `\.\$' (i.e., a
|math_shift| character) is scanned. We must check to see whether this
`\.\$' is immediately followed by another, in case display math mode is
called for.

@<Cases of |main_control| that build...@>=
hmode+math_shift:init_math;

@ @<Declare act...@>=
procedure init_math;
label reswitch,found,not_found,done;
var w:scaled; {new or partial |pre_display_size|}
@!l:scaled; {new |display_width|}
@!s:scaled; {new |display_indent|}
@!p:pointer; {current node when calculating |pre_display_size|}
@!q:pointer; {glue specification when calculating |pre_display_size|}
@!f:internal_font_number; {font in current |char_node|}
@!n:integer; {scope of paragraph shape specification}
@!v:scaled; {|w| plus possible glue amount}
@!d:scaled; {increment to |v|}
begin get_token; {|get_x_token| would fail on \.{\\ifmmode}\thinspace!}
if (cur_cmd=math_shift)and(mode>0) then @<Go into display math mode@>
else  begin back_input; @<Go into ordinary math mode@>;
  end;
end;

@ @<Go into ordinary math mode@>=
begin push_math(math_shift_group); eq_word_define(int_base+cur_fam_code,-1);
if every_math<>null then begin_token_list(every_math,every_math_text);
end

@ We get into ordinary math mode from display math mode when `\.{\\eqno}' or
`\.{\\leqno}' appears. In such cases |cur_chr| will be 0 or~1, respectively;
the value of |cur_chr| is placed onto |save_stack| for safe keeping.

@<Cases of |main_control| that build...@>=
mmode+eq_no: if privileged then
  if cur_group=math_shift_group then start_eq_no
  else off_save;

@ @<Put each...@>=
primitive("eqno",eq_no,0);
@!@:eq_no_}{\.{\\eqno} primitive@>
primitive("leqno",eq_no,1);
@!@:leq_no_}{\.{\\leqno} primitive@>

@ When \TeX\ is in display math mode, |cur_group=math_shift_group|,
so it is not necessary for the |start_eq_no| procedure to test for
this condition.

@<Declare act...@>=
procedure start_eq_no;
begin saved(0):=cur_chr; incr(save_ptr);
@<Go into ordinary math mode@>;
end;

@ @<Cases of |print_cmd_chr|...@>=
eq_no:if chr_code=1 then print_esc("leqno")@+else print_esc("eqno");

@ @<Forbidden...@>=non_math(eq_no),

@ When we enter display math mode, we need to call |line_break| to
process the partial paragraph that has just been interrupted by the
display. Then we can set the proper values of |display_width| and
|display_indent| and |pre_display_size|.

@<Go into display math mode@>=
begin if head=tail then {`\.{\\noindent\$\$}' or `\.{\$\${ }\$\$}'}
  begin pop_nest; w:=-max_dimen;
  end
else  begin line_break(display_widow_penalty);@/
  @<Calculate the natural width, |w|, by which the characters of the
    final line extend to the right of the reference point,
    plus two ems; or set |w:=max_dimen| if the non-blank information
    on that line is affected by stretching or shrinking@>;
  end;
{now we are in vertical mode, working on the list that will contain the display}
@<Calculate the length, |l|, and the shift amount, |s|, of the display lines@>;
push_math(math_shift_group); mode:=mmode;
eq_word_define(int_base+cur_fam_code,-1);@/
eq_word_define(dimen_base+pre_display_size_code,w);
eq_word_define(dimen_base+display_width_code,l);
eq_word_define(dimen_base+display_indent_code,s);
if every_display<>null then begin_token_list(every_display,every_display_text);
if nest_ptr=1 then build_page;
end
```

Comment: Yes, I know $$ is an environment of tex not of latex. However, I also want to know what does define it! If possible, please let me where I can find!

Comment: @phchon - Please also read [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40531/5001) to the query [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001) It explains (among quite a few other things...) how the LaTeX commands `\[` and `\]` are based on the TeX-primitive `$$` directive. The simple matter is that a LaTeX document should **NOT** contain any `$$` directives.

Comment: [TeX by Topic](https://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic), chapter 24, has an overview of how `$$` works under the hood. However, from your previous question, if your goal is to output to Moodle XML, keep in mind that you'll be constrained mostly by how Moodle works, not by TeX. As a result, it may not be fruitful to attempt to dig into TeX internals.

Comment: @phchon I added the code as requested

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much.