# Why does LaTeX (contrarily to TeX) not allow catcode changes in footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, catcodes

In Plain TeX the following compiles with no error

```
Hello\footnote*{\tt\catcode92=12 \world}!
\bye
```

The analog in LaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello\footnote{\ttfamily\catcode92=12 \world}!
\end{document}
```

fails with error message

```
 ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

 --- TeX said --- <argument> ...ces \ttfamily \catcode 92=12 \world 
                                                   \@finalstrut \strutbox  l.4 Hello\footnote{\ttfamily\catcode92=12 \world}
                                                  !
```

which just says that `\world` was still seen as an undefined control sequence. So it is as if the (mandatory) argument to `\footnote` was treated as is usual with macro arguments and the consequence is that one can not use `\verb` in the LaTeX footnotes.

What are the rationale or implementation constraints which led to this impoverished (in that respect) `\footnote` concept in LaTeX?

Comment: There's no note about this in `source2e`. I guess that Leslie Lamport used a simplified definition and LaTeX2e didn't change it.

Comment: Don't you need to restore the catcode of ASCII92 (the backslash character) back to `0` before the end of the `footnote` field? (The `\footnote` command in PlainTeX is defined differently from the one in LaTeX.)

Comment: @Mico no I don't. Plain TeX creates a group, so that for example one can change font in the footnote without contaminating the main text.

Comment: @egreg I wonder if Leslie was worried that the plain approach means that `\footnote` is inconsistent with other arguments (where verbatim cannot be used), so was 'tidying up'. I guess we could ask him :-)

Comment: @jfbu Also in LaTeX the footnote text is typeset in a group. This has nothing to do with the "changing catcodes" problem.

Comment: @egreg yes but did I say anything to let believe I was thinking it had something to do? I just replied to `Mico`'s comment.... maybe I should have written "Plain TeX _also_ creates a group"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

LaTeX has always done this. Certainly at LaTeX2e it was a concious decision not to change it. The documented behaviour is that `\verb` does not work in the argument of another command. If you make it work in `\footnote` you have to explain why it doesn't work in `\marginpar` or in `\footnote` that is inside `\textrm{...}` or any other place it would fail. Basically LaTeX does not support changing catcodes mid-document. There are almost always better more robust techniques that could be used, for example `\footnote{\ttfamily\string\world}` works in LaTeX even if that is already in the argument of another macro.

Comment: All rules should admit exceptions. The normal LaTeX user has to read his/her way through complicated stuff of "moving arguments needing protection". Compared to that, explaining that `\footnote` allows a bit more of flexibility than other commands seems as it should not be that traumatizing to the average LaTeX user. And yes, I often use  `\ttfamily\string` even in the body, although braces then need to be `\{` or `\string{`. I know I can not imagine the globality of the difficulties faced at the time of LaTeX2e, but I am not convinced by that one.

Comment: but why (apart from the fact that plain does it) would one even think of special casing footnote here, why footnote and not marginpar or parbox or ...  Plain has far fewer commands and far less consistency of syntax anyway so it is less of an issue there. For similar reasons \mbox and \sbox parse their arguments as macros in 2e

Comment: well, I would vote for having `marginpar` and `footnote` behave similarly to one another, and allow the same freedom therein as in the general text. And with regards to consistency of syntax wouldn't it have required to make `footnote` an environment, too?

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, this snippet works in ConTeXt.

```
\starttext
Hello\footnote{\tt\catcode92=12 \world}!
\stoptext
```

but, as pointed out by David, it fails for `\inmargin` (which is the ConTeXt equivalent of `\marginpar`). This is not surprising; all catcode changes fail with macros that parse their argument. Having said that, the standard way in ConTeXt to take care of catcode changes is to use buffers.

```
\starttext
\startbuffer[catcode]
\catcode92=12 \world
\stopbuffer
Hello\inmargin{\tt\getbuffer[catcode]}!
\stoptext
```

which works correctly in both MkII and MkIV. In LaTeX, the `filecontents` environment is the closest to buffers. (See [LaTeX equivalent of ConTeXt buffers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5681/323)).

Comment: `filecontents` (or `filecontents*`) work indeed. Two defects though: this is preamble-only, and after having been used once they will not overwrite the existing file. This ConTeXt `buffer` facility indeed is neat. Thanks for the pointer.